# How to pivot Spark DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I am starting to use Spark DataFrames and I need to be able to pivot the data to create multiple columns out of 1 column with multiple rows.  There is built in functionality for that in Scalding and I believe in Pandas in Python, but I can't find anything for the new Spark Dataframe.

I assume I can write custom function of some sort that will do this but I'm not even sure how to start, especially since I am a novice with Spark.  If anyone knows how to do this with built-in functionality or suggestions for how to write something in Scala, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260015/reshaping-pivoting-data-in-spark-rdd-and-or-spark-dataframes/) where I posted a native Spark approach that doesn't need to know the column/category names ahead of time.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33799008/1560062) by [David Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000823/user2000823) Spark provides [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html) function since version 1.6. General syntax looks as follows:

```
df
  .groupBy(grouping_columns)
  .pivot(pivot_column, [values]) 
  .agg(aggregate_expressions)
```

Usage examples using [`nycflights13`](https://github.com/hadley/nycflights13) and `csv` format:

**Python**:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg

flights = (sqlContext
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .options(inferSchema="true", header="true")
    .load("flights.csv")
    .na.drop())

flights.registerTempTable("flights")
sqlContext.cacheTable("flights")

gexprs = ("origin", "dest", "carrier")
aggexpr = avg("arr_delay")

flights.count()
## 336776

%timeit -n10 flights.groupBy(*gexprs ).pivot("hour").agg(aggexpr).count()
## 10 loops, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop
```

**Scala**:

```scala
val flights = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .options(Map("inferSchema" -> "true", "header" -> "true"))
  .load("flights.csv")

flights
  .groupBy($"origin", $"dest", $"carrier")
  .pivot("hour")
  .agg(avg($"arr_delay"))
```

**Java**:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("header", "true")
        .load("flights.csv");

df.groupBy(col("origin"), col("dest"), col("carrier"))
        .pivot("hour")
        .agg(avg(col("arr_delay")));
```

**R / SparkR**:

```r
library(magrittr)

flights <- read.df("flights.csv", source="csv", header=TRUE, inferSchema=TRUE)

flights %>% 
  groupBy("origin", "dest", "carrier") %>% 
  pivot("hour") %>% 
  agg(avg(column("arr_delay")))
```

**R / sparklyr**

```
library(dplyr)

flights <- spark_read_csv(sc, "flights", "flights.csv")

avg.arr.delay <- function(gdf) {
   expr <- invoke_static(
      sc,
      "org.apache.spark.sql.functions",
      "avg",
      "arr_delay"
    )
    gdf %>% invoke("agg", expr, list())
}

flights %>% 
  sdf_pivot(origin + dest + carrier ~  hour, fun.aggregate=avg.arr.delay)
```

**SQL**:

Note that PIVOT keyword in Spark SQL is supported starting from version 2.4.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW flights 
USING csv 
OPTIONS (header 'true', path 'flights.csv', inferSchema 'true') ;

 SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT origin, dest, carrier, arr_delay, hour FROM flights
 ) PIVOT (
   avg(arr_delay)
   FOR hour IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
                13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
 );
```

**Example data**:

```
"year","month","day","dep_time","sched_dep_time","dep_delay","arr_time","sched_arr_time","arr_delay","carrier","flight","tailnum","origin","dest","air_time","distance","hour","minute","time_hour"
2013,1,1,517,515,2,830,819,11,"UA",1545,"N14228","EWR","IAH",227,1400,5,15,2013-01-01 05:00:00
2013,1,1,533,529,4,850,830,20,"UA",1714,"N24211","LGA","IAH",227,1416,5,29,2013-01-01 05:00:00
2013,1,1,542,540,2,923,850,33,"AA",1141,"N619AA","JFK","MIA",160,1089,5,40,2013-01-01 05:00:00
2013,1,1,544,545,-1,1004,1022,-18,"B6",725,"N804JB","JFK","BQN",183,1576,5,45,2013-01-01 05:00:00
2013,1,1,554,600,-6,812,837,-25,"DL",461,"N668DN","LGA","ATL",116,762,6,0,2013-01-01 06:00:00
2013,1,1,554,558,-4,740,728,12,"UA",1696,"N39463","EWR","ORD",150,719,5,58,2013-01-01 05:00:00
2013,1,1,555,600,-5,913,854,19,"B6",507,"N516JB","EWR","FLL",158,1065,6,0,2013-01-01 06:00:00
2013,1,1,557,600,-3,709,723,-14,"EV",5708,"N829AS","LGA","IAD",53,229,6,0,2013-01-01 06:00:00
2013,1,1,557,600,-3,838,846,-8,"B6",79,"N593JB","JFK","MCO",140,944,6,0,2013-01-01 06:00:00
2013,1,1,558,600,-2,753,745,8,"AA",301,"N3ALAA","LGA","ORD",138,733,6,0,2013-01-01 06:00:00
```

**Performance considerations**:

Generally speaking pivoting is an expensive operation.

- if you can, try to provide `values` list, as this avoids an extra hit to compute the uniques:

  ```py
    vs = list(range(25))
    %timeit -n10 flights.groupBy(*gexprs ).pivot("hour", vs).agg(aggexpr).count()
    ## 10 loops, best of 3: 392 ms per loop
  ```
- [in some cases it proved to be beneficial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35427812/1560062) (likely no longer worth the effort in [2.0 or later](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13749)) to `repartition` and / or pre-aggregate the data
- for reshaping only, you can use `first`: [Pivot String column on Pyspark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37486910/1560062)

**Related questions**:

- [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41670103/8371915)
- [Unpivot in Spark SQL / PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42465568/8371915)
- [Transpose column to row with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37864222/8371915)

Comment: What if the pivoted dataframe is too big to fit on memory. How can I do it directly on disk?

Comment: how should this be changed aggexpr = avg("arr_delay") in order to pivot more columns, not just the 1

Comment: In SQL solution(not Scala), I can see you use a hardcoded list '(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)'. Is there any way to use all values taken from another column? I searched over the internet and this site but didn't find anything.

Comment: Same question as @Windoze. The SQL solution is not really equivalent to others if one needs to supply the column list manually. Is it possible to get the list by a select subquery?

Comment: Why does it drop columns not included in group by?

Comment: Any feedback on this @Windoze? I am searching frantically for a solution to this!

Answer (score 16):

I overcame this by writing a for loop to dynamically create a SQL query.  Say I have:

```
id  tag  value
1   US    50
1   UK    100
1   Can   125
2   US    75
2   UK    150
2   Can   175
```

and I want:

```
id  US  UK   Can
1   50  100  125
2   75  150  175
```

I can create a list with the value I want to pivot and then create a string containing the SQL query I need.

```
val countries = List("US", "UK", "Can")
val numCountries = countries.length - 1

var query = "select *, "
for (i <- 0 to numCountries-1) {
  query += """case when tag = """" + countries(i) + """" then value else 0 end as """ + countries(i) + ", "
}
query += """case when tag = """" + countries.last + """" then value else 0 end as """ + countries.last + " from myTable"

myDataFrame.registerTempTable("myTable")
val myDF1 = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

I can create similar query to then do the aggregation.  Not a very elegant solution but it works and is flexible for any list of values, which can also be passed in as an argument when your code is called.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your example, but I get an "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'US' given input columns id, tag, value"

Comment: That has to do with the quotes.  If you look at the resulting text string what you would get is 'case when tag = US', so Spark thinks thats a column name rather than a text value.  What you really want to see is 'case when tag = "US" '.  I have edited the above answer to have the correct set up for quotes.

Comment: But as also mentioned, this is fuctionality is now native to Spark using the pivot command.

Answer (score 11):

A pivot operator has been added to the Spark dataframe API, and is part of Spark 1.6.

See https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/7841 for details.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved a similar problem using dataframes with the following steps:

Create columns for all your countries, with 'value' as the value:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val countries = List("US", "UK", "Can")
val countryValue = udf{(countryToCheck: String, countryInRow: String, value: Long) =>
  if(countryToCheck == countryInRow) value else 0
}
val countryFuncs = countries.map{country => (dataFrame: DataFrame) => dataFrame.withColumn(country, countryValue(lit(country), df("tag"), df("value"))) }
val dfWithCountries = Function.chain(countryFuncs)(df).drop("tag").drop("value")
```

Your dataframe 'dfWithCountries' will look like this:

```
+--+--+---+---+
|id|US| UK|Can|
+--+--+---+---+
| 1|50|  0|  0|
| 1| 0|100|  0|
| 1| 0|  0|125|
| 2|75|  0|  0|
| 2| 0|150|  0|
| 2| 0|  0|175|
+--+--+---+---+
```

Now you can sum together all the values for your desired result:

```
dfWithCountries.groupBy("id").sum(countries: _*).show
```

Result:

```
+--+-------+-------+--------+
|id|SUM(US)|SUM(UK)|SUM(Can)|
+--+-------+-------+--------+
| 1|     50|    100|     125|
| 2|     75|    150|     175|
+--+-------+-------+--------+
```

It's not a very elegant solution though.  I had to create a chain of functions to add in all the columns.  Also if I have lots of countries, I will expand my temporary data set to a very wide set with lots of zeroes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a **SIMPLE** method for pivoting :

```
  id  tag  value
  1   US    50
  1   UK    100
  1   Can   125
  2   US    75
  2   UK    150
  2   Can   175

  import sparkSession.implicits._

  val data = Seq(
    (1,"US",50),
    (1,"UK",100),
    (1,"Can",125),
    (2,"US",75),
    (2,"UK",150),
    (2,"Can",175),
  )

  val dataFrame = data.toDF("id","tag","value")

  val df2 = dataFrame
                    .groupBy("id")
                    .pivot("tag")
                    .max("value")
  df2.show()

+---+---+---+---+
| id|Can| UK| US|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|125|100| 50|
|  2|175|150| 75|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 4):

There is simple and elegant solution.

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from k_tags limit 10").show()
+---------------+-------------+------+
|           imsi|         name| value|
+---------------+-------------+------+
|246021000000000|          age|    37|
|246021000000000|       gender|Female|
|246021000000000|         arpu|    22|
|246021000000000|   DeviceType| Phone|
|246021000000000|DataAllowance|   6GB|
+---------------+-------------+------+

scala> spark.sql("select * from k_tags limit 10").groupBy($"imsi").pivot("name").agg(min($"value")).show()
+---------------+-------------+----------+---+----+------+
|           imsi|DataAllowance|DeviceType|age|arpu|gender|
+---------------+-------------+----------+---+----+------+
|246021000000000|          6GB|     Phone| 37|  22|Female|
|246021000000001|          1GB|     Phone| 72|  10|  Male|
+---------------+-------------+----------+---+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples of pivot operation on dataset/dataframe, but I could not find many using SQL. Here is an example that worked for me.

```
create or replace temporary view faang 
as SELECT stock.date AS `Date`,
    stock.adj_close AS `Price`,
    stock.symbol as `Symbol` 
FROM stock  
WHERE (stock.symbol rlike '^(FB|AAPL|GOOG|AMZN)$') and year(date) > 2010;


SELECT * from faang 

PIVOT (max(price) for symbol in ('AAPL', 'FB', 'GOOG', 'AMZN')) order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially i adopted Al M's solution. Later took the same thought and rewrote this function as a transpose function.

This method transposes any df rows to columns of any data-format with using key and value column

**for input csv**

```
id,tag,value
1,US,50a
1,UK,100
1,Can,125
2,US,75
2,UK,150
2,Can,175
```

**ouput**

```
+--+---+---+---+
|id| UK| US|Can|
+--+---+---+---+
| 2|150| 75|175|
| 1|100|50a|125|
+--+---+---+---+
```

**transpose method :**

```
def transpose(hc : HiveContext , df: DataFrame,compositeId: List[String], key: String, value: String) = {

val distinctCols =   df.select(key).distinct.map { r => r(0) }.collect().toList

val rdd = df.map { row =>
(compositeId.collect { case id => row.getAs(id).asInstanceOf[Any] },
scala.collection.mutable.Map(row.getAs(key).asInstanceOf[Any] -> row.getAs(value).asInstanceOf[Any]))
}
val pairRdd = rdd.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
val rowRdd = pairRdd.map(r => dynamicRow(r, distinctCols))
hc.createDataFrame(rowRdd, getSchema(df.schema, compositeId, (key, distinctCols)))

}

private def dynamicRow(r: (List[Any], scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any, Any]), colNames: List[Any]) = {
val cols = colNames.collect { case col => r._2.getOrElse(col.toString(), null) }
val array = r._1 ++ cols
Row(array: _*)
}

private  def getSchema(srcSchema: StructType, idCols: List[String], distinctCols: (String, List[Any])): StructType = {
val idSchema = idCols.map { idCol => srcSchema.apply(idCol) }
val colSchema = srcSchema.apply(distinctCols._1)
val colsSchema = distinctCols._2.map { col => StructField(col.asInstanceOf[String], colSchema.dataType, colSchema.nullable) }
StructType(idSchema ++ colsSchema)
}
```

**main snippet**

```
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField


...
...
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val dfdata1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("data.csv")
    dfdata1.show()  
    val dfOutput = transpose(new HiveContext(sc), dfdata1, List("id"), "tag", "value")
    dfOutput.show

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The built-in spark pivot function is inefficient. The bellow implementation works on spark 2.4+ - the idea is to aggregate a map and extract the values as columns. The only limitation is it does not handle aggregate function in the pivoted columns, only column(s).

On a 8M table, those functions applies on **3 secondes**, versus **40 minutes** in the built-in spark version:

```py
# pass an optional list of string to avoid computation of columns
def pivot(df, group_by, key, aggFunction, levels=[]):
    if not levels:
        levels = [row[key] for row in df.filter(col(key).isNotNull()).groupBy(col(key)).agg(count(key)).select(key).collect()]
    return df.filter(col(key).isin(*levels) == True).groupBy(group_by).agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(key, expr(aggFunction)))).alias("group_map")).select([group_by] + ["group_map." + l for l in levels])

# Usage
pivot(df, "id", "key", "value")
pivot(df, "id", "key", "array(value)")
```

```scala
// pass an optional list of string to avoid computation of columns
  def pivot(df: DataFrame, groupBy: Column, key: Column, aggFunct: String, _levels: List[String] = Nil): DataFrame = {
    val levels =
      if (_levels.isEmpty) df.filter(key.isNotNull).select(key).distinct().collect().map(row => row.getString(0)).toList
      else _levels

    df
      .filter(key.isInCollection(levels))
      .groupBy(groupBy)
      .agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(key, expr(aggFunct)))).alias("group_map"))
      .select(groupBy.toString, levels.map(f => "group_map." + f): _*)
  }

// Usage:
pivot(df, col("id"), col("key"), "value")
pivot(df, col("id"), col("key"), "array(value)")
```

Answer (score -1):

Spark has been providing improvements to Pivoting the Spark DataFrame. A pivot function has been added to the Spark DataFrame API to Spark 1.6 version and it has a performance issue and that has been corrected in Spark 2.0

however, if you are using lower version; note that pivot is a very expensive operation hence, it is recommended to provide column data (if known) as an argument to function as shown below.

```
val countries = Seq("USA","China","Canada","Mexico")
val pivotDF = df.groupBy("Product").pivot("Country", countries).sum("Amount")
pivotDF.show()
```

This has been explained detailed at [Pivoting and Unpivoting Spark DataFrame](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/)

Happy Learning !!