# Collapse a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I am using **Spark with Scala**. Spark version **1.5** and I am trying to transform input dataframe which has name value combination to a new dataframe in which all name to be transposed to columns and values as rows.

I/P DataFrame:

```
ID  Name    Value  
1   Country US  
2   Country US  
2   State   NY  
3   Country UK  
4   Country India  
4   State   MH  
5   Country US  
5   State   NJ  
5   County  Hudson
```

[Link here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UbY0.png)

Transposed DataFrame

```
ID  Country State   County  
1   US      NULL    NULL  
2   US      NY      NULL  
3   UK      NULL    NULL  
4   India   MH      NULL  
5   US      NJ      Hudson
```

[Link to transposed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wilHd.png)
Seems like pivot would help in this use case, but its not supported in spark 1.5.x version.

Any pointers/help?

Answer (score 4):

This is a really ugly data but you can always filter and join:

```
val names = Seq("Country", "State", "County")

names.map(name => 
  df.where($"Name" === name).select($"ID", $"Value".alias("name"))
).reduce((df1, df2) => df1.join(df2, Seq("ID"), "leftouter"))
```

`map` creates a list of three `DataFrames` where each table contains records containing only a single name. Next we simply `reduce` this list using left outer join. So putting it all together you get something like this:

```
(left-outer-join
  (left-outer-join 
    (where df (=== name "Country"))
    (where df (=== name "State")))
  (where df (=== name "County")))
```

**Note**: If you use Spark >= 1.6 with Python or Scala, or Spark >= 2.0 with R, just use pivot with `first`:

- [Reshaping/Pivoting data in Spark RDD and/or Spark DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30260015/1560062)
- [How to pivot DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30244910/1560062)