# PySpark: Create Instants DataFrame from sequential observation dataframe

Tags: python, time-series, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine you got a Dataframe containing value observations of variables. Each observation is saved as a triple Variable, Timestamp, Value. This layout is somewhat a "[observation dataframe](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/spark-ts-a-new-library-for-analyzing-time-series-data-with-apache-spark/)".

```
#Variable     Time                Value
#852-YF-007   2016-05-10 23:00:00 4
#852-YF-007   2016-05-11 04:00:00 4
#...
#852-YF-008   2016-05-10 23:00:00 5
#852-YF-008   2016-05-11 04:00:00 3
#...
#852-YF-009   2016-05-10 23:00:00 2
#852-YF-009   2016-05-11 04:00:00 9
#...
```

That data is loaded into a Spark Dataframe and the timestamps are sampled so that we have one value for each variable for a specific timestamp.

**Question:** How can I convert/transpose that efficiently into a ["Instants Dataframe"](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/spark-ts-a-new-library-for-analyzing-time-series-data-with-apache-spark/) like this:

```
#Time                    852-YF-007     852-YF-008     852-YF-009
#2016-05-10 23:00:00     4              5              2
#2016-05-11 04:00:00     4              3              9
#...
```

The number of columns depends on the number of variables. Each column is the timeseries (all sampled values for that variables) while the rows are the timestamps. **Note:** the number of timestamps will be much larger than the number of variables.

**Update:** It's related to pivot-tables but I do not have a fixed number of columns. That number varies by the number of variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping/Pivoting data in Spark RDD and/or Spark DataFrames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260015/reshaping-pivoting-data-in-spark-rdd-and-or-spark-dataframes)

Comment: Hmm, not that sure because that example you mentioned has a fixed schema and fixed number of columns. Maybe someone can give a sample using spark-ts?