# How to unstack dataset (using pivot)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried the new "pivot" function of 1.6 on a [larger stacked dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/worldbank/world-development-indicators/downloads/world-development-indicators-release-2016-01-28-06-31-53.zip). It has 5,656,458 rows and the `IndicatorCode` column has 1344 different codes.

The idea was to use pivot to "unstack" (in pandas terms) this data set and have a column for each IndicatorCode.

```
schema = StructType([ \
   StructField("CountryName", StringType(), True), \
   StructField("CountryCode", StringType(), True), \
   StructField("IndicatorName", StringType(), True), \
   StructField("IndicatorCode", StringType(), True), \
   StructField("Year", IntegerType(), True), \
   StructField("Value", DoubleType(), True)  \
])

data = sqlContext.read.load('hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/world-development-indicators/Indicators.csv', 
                            format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
                            header='true', 
                            schema=schema)

data2 = indicators_csv.withColumn("IndicatorCode2", regexp_replace("indicatorCode", "\.", "_"))\
                      .select(["CountryCode", "IndicatorCode2", "Year", "Value"])

columns = [row.IndicatorCode2 for row in data2.select("IndicatorCode2").distinct().collect()]

data3 = data2.groupBy(["Year", "CountryCode"])\
             .pivot("IndicatorCode2", columns)\
             .max("Value")
```

While this returned successfully, `data3.first()` never returned a result (I interrupted on my standalone using 3 cores after 10 min).

My approach using `RDD` and `aggregateByKey` worked well, so I'm not searching for a solution about how to do it, but whether pivot with DataFrames can also do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, pivoting is not a very efficient operation in general and there is not much you can do about it using `DataFrame` API. One thing you can try though is to `repartition` your data:

```
(data2
  .repartition("Year", "CountryCode")
  .groupBy("Year", "CountryCode")
  .pivot("IndicatorCode2", columns)
  .max("Value"))
```

or even aggregate:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

(df
    .groupBy("Year", "CountryCode", "IndicatorCode")
    .agg(max("Value").alias("Value"))
    .groupBy("Year", "CountryCode")
    .pivot("IndicatorCode", columns)
    .max("Value"))
```

before applying `pivot`. The idea behind both solutions is the same. Instead of moving large expanded `Rows` move narrow dense data and expand locally.

Comment: Thanks. I find it interesting that something that can be done on one node with pandas in 26 sec (16 sec loading/parsing csv amd 10 sec for unstacking)

Comment: ...  is that difficult using spark with four of these machines. With RDD I am currently at about 100 sec - I will try to find a faster way in Spark.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me. Local processing is fast because it just moving things in memory.  Spark has to perform a lot of work, even locally, and makes specific assumptions about the data which can make this type of operations inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Spark 2.0 introduced [SPARK-13749](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13749) an implementation of pivot that is faster for a large number of pivot column values.

Testing with Spark 2.1.0 on my computer, your example now runs in 48 seconds.