# How can I pivot on multiple columns separately in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, multiple-columns

Is there a possibility to make a pivot for different columns at once in PySpark?
I have a dataframe like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
import pandas as pd
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame([[1, 'str1', 'str4'], [1, 'str1', 'str4'], [1, 'str2', 'str4'], [1, 'str2', 'str5'],
        [1, 'str3', 'str5'], [2, 'str2', 'str4'], [2, 'str2', 'str4'], [2, 'str3', 'str4'],
        [2, 'str3', 'str5']], columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2'])
)
# +----+------+------+
# | id | col1 | col2 |
# +----+------+------+
# |  1 | str1 | str4 |
# |  1 | str1 | str4 |
# |  1 | str2 | str4 |
# |  1 | str2 | str5 |
# |  1 | str3 | str5 |
# |  2 | str2 | str4 |
# |  2 | str2 | str4 |
# |  2 | str3 | str4 |
# |  2 | str3 | str5 |
# +----+------+------+
```

I want to pivot it on multiple columns ("col1", "col2", ...) to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | col1_str1 | col1_str2 | col1_str3 | col2_str4 | col2_str5 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         2 |         2 |         1 |         3 |         3 |
|  2 |         0 |         2 |         2 |         3 |         1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I've found a solution that works:

```py
sdf_pivot_col1 = (
    sdf
    .groupby('id')
    .pivot('col1')
    .agg(sf.count('id'))
)
sdf_pivot_col2 = (
    sdf
    .groupby('id')
    .pivot('col2')
    .agg(sf.count('id'))
)

sdf_result = (
    sdf
    .select('id').distinct()
    .join(sdf_pivot_col1, on = 'id' , how = 'left')
    .join(sdf_pivot_col2, on = 'id' , how = 'left')
).show()

# +---+----+----+----+----+----+
# | id|str1|str2|str3|str4|str5|
# +---+----+----+----+----+----+
# |  1|   2|   2|   1|   3|   2|
# |  2|null|   2|   2|   3|   1|
# +---+----+----+----+----+----+
```

But I'm looking for a more compact solution.

Comment: Have you maybe checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035940/how-to-pivot-on-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql . As suggested in one of the answers, consider caching the input data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the link of @mrjoseph I came up with the following solution:
It works, it's more clean, but I still don't like the joins...

```
def pivot_udf(df, *cols):
    mydf = df.select('id').drop_duplicates()
    for c in cols:
        mydf = mydf.join(
            df
            .withColumn('combcol',sf.concat(sf.lit('{}_'.format(c)),df[c]))
            .groupby('id.pivot('combcol.agg(sf.count(c)),
            how = 'left', 
            on = 'id'
        )
    return mydf

pivot_udf(sdf, 'col1','col2').show()

+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id|col1_str1|col1_str2|col1_str3|col2_str4|col2_str5|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1|        2|        2|        1|        3|        2|
|  2|     null|        2|        2|        3|        1|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

cols = [x for x in sdf.columns if x!='id']
df_array = [sdf.withColumn('col', F.concat(F.lit(x), F.lit('_'), F.col(x))).select('id', 'col') for x in cols]

reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_array).groupby('id').pivot('col').agg(F.count('col')).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id|col1_str1|col1_str2|col1_str3|col2_str4|col2_str5|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1|        2|        2|        1|        3|        2|
|  2|     null|        2|        2|        3|        1|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is not pivoting on multiple columns (*[this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035940/how-to-pivot-on-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql/73850575#73850575) pivoting on multiple columns*).
What you really want is pivoting on one column, but first moving both column values into one...

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = [c for c in sdf.columns if c!= 'id']
sdf = (sdf
    .withColumn('_pivot', F.explode(F.array(
        *[F.concat(F.lit(f'{c}_'), c) for c in cols]
    ))).groupBy('id').pivot('_pivot').count().fillna(0)
)

sdf.show()
# +---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
# | id|col1_str1|col1_str2|col1_str3|col2_str4|col2_str5|
# +---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
# |  1|        2|        2|        1|        3|        2|
# |  2|        0|        2|        2|        3|        1|
# +---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```