# Pyspark Dataframe Convert category row values into columns with aggregate on multiple columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot

I have a PySpark dataframe as below:

| Id | variable | old_val | new_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | frequency | 2.0 | 25.0 |
| a1 | latitude | 25.762 | 25.729 |
| a1 | longitude | -80.192 | -80.436 |
| a2 | frequency | 1.0 | 5.0 |
| a2 | latitude | 25.7 | 25.762 |
| a2 | longitude | -80.436 | -80.192 |

I am trying to reflect the changes by "id".

**I would like to achieve the below ideal state:**

| Id | freq_old_val | freq_new_val | lat_old_val | lat_new_val | long_old_val | long_new_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2.0 | 25.0 | 25.762 | 25.729 | -80.192 | -80.436 |
| a2 | 1.0 | 5.0 | 25.7 | 25.762 | -80.436 | -80.192 |

**My useless code with a useful attempt**

I am unsure if i must use explode. I am also unsure if agg can be passed with two column values.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("id").pivot("variable").agg(first("old_val","new_val"))
```

I am fairly new to pyspark, working my way through it.
Any guidance and help is highly appreciated.
Thank you for taking the time to guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think similar question is already answered here: [How to pivot on multiple columns in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035940/how-to-pivot-on-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql)

Please comment if it is not clear