# How to create new columns by pivoting existing table columns in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe in the below format

[image]I

I am tring to create a pyspark dataframe in the below format

[image]

I tried doing this by splitting the source dataframe into three by filtering on order value (1,2,3 these are present for the every key) and joined them using a left join using key and was able to get the dataframe in required format.

But is there any better way to solve this in pyspark?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73506389/8279585) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ORDER1`, `ORDER2` and `ORDER3` columns are a bit redundant. If you can live without them, you can combine a `groupBy` and `pivot` like so:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1, "ABC"),
        (1, 2, "BCD"),
        (1, 3, "DEF"),
        (2, 1, "EFG"),
        (2, 2, "GHI"),
        (2, 3, "HIJ"),
        (3, 1, "EFG"),
        (3, 2, "BCD"),
        (3, 3, "HIJ"),
    ],
    ["KEY", "ORDER", "RESP"]
)

output = df.groupBy("KEY").pivot("ORDER").agg(collect_list("RESP"))

output.show()
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|KEY|    1|    2|    3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|[ABC]|[BCD]|[DEF]|
|  2|[EFG]|[GHI]|[HIJ]|
|  3|[EFG]|[BCD]|[HIJ]|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

I'm using `collect_list` to make sure that if you have more than 1 `RESP` value for specific combination of `KEY` and `ORDER`, that you don't lose it but it just gets put inside of an array. So all the values that you're seeing in this dataframe are arrays (with 1 element for your example).

If you're sure you only have 1 value for a combination of `KEY` and `ORDER` and you don't want arrays as values, you can also use `first()` instead of `collect_list()`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

...

output = df.groupBy("KEY").pivot("ORDER").agg(first("RESP"))

output.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|KEY|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|ABC|BCD|DEF|
|  2|EFG|GHI|HIJ|
|  3|EFG|BCD|HIJ|
+---+---+---+---+
```