# Pyspark Transpose multiple rows in multiple columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, transpose

I want to transpose multiple rows of a datafarme in multiple columns, as shown below:

Initial df:

| Code | Cat | Count | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | A | 1 | 10 |
| S1 | B | 2 | 15 |
| S2 | A | 3 | 20 |
| S2 | B | 4 | 25 |

Final df:

| Code | Count A | Value A | Count B | Value B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 1 | 10 | 2 | 15 |
| S2 | 3 | 20 | 4 | 25 |

Trying the pivot function I can transpose only one between Count and Value

`df = df.groupBy("Code").pivot("Cat").agg(f.first("Count"))`

| Code | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 1 | 2 |
| S2 | 3 | 4 |

Making two intermediate dataframes and then join them could be the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to join, you can do multiple aggregations in one go

```
result = df.groupBy('Code').pivot('Cat').agg(F.first('Count').alias('Count'), 
                                             F.first('Value').alias('Value'))
```

---

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Code|A_Count|A_Value|B_Count|B_Value|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  S2|      3|     20|      4|     25|
|  S1|      1|     10|      2|     15|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Perfect! It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I followed two methods, the one given in above answer and the one recommended here. Both the answer are already answered before on stack overflow, based on top vote i would go with first approach.

[How to pivot on multiple columns in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035940/how-to-pivot-on-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql)

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame(
        data=[
            Row(Code='S1', Cat='A', Count=1, Value=10),
            Row(Code='S1', Cat='B', Count=2, Value=15),
            Row(Code='S2', Cat='A', Count=3, Value=20),
            Row(Code='S2', Cat='B', Count=4, Value=25),
        ], schema="""`Code` STRING, `Cat` STRING, `Count` INTEGER, `Value` INTEGER"""
    )

    df.show()

    print("first solution")

    (
        df.groupBy('Code')
        .pivot('Cat')
        .agg(
            F.first('Count').alias('Count'), 
            F.first('Value').alias('Value')
        ).show()
    )

    print("Second solution")

    def pivot_udf(df, *cols):
        mydf = df.select('Code').drop_duplicates()
        mydf.cache
        for c in cols:
            mydf = mydf.join(df.withColumn('combcol', F.concat(F.lit('{}_'.format(c)), df['Cat'])).groupby('Code').pivot('combcol').agg(F.first(c)),'Code')
        return mydf

    pivot_udf(df, 'Count', 'Value').show()


These are the output 
+----+---+-----+-----+                                                          
|Code|Cat|Count|Value|
+----+---+-----+-----+
|  S1|  A|    1|   10|
|  S1|  B|    2|   15|
|  S2|  A|    3|   20|
|  S2|  B|    4|   25|
+----+---+-----+-----+

first solution
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Code|A_Count|A_Value|B_Count|B_Value|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  S1|      1|     10|      2|     15|
|  S2|      3|     20|      4|     25|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+

Second solution
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Code|Count_A|Count_B|Value_A|Value_B|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  S1|      1|      2|     10|     15|
|  S2|      3|      4|     20|     25|
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am also using the first solution.