# Convert a RDD of Tuples of Varying Sizes to a DataFrame in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, tuples, pyspark

I am having difficulty in converting an RDD of the follwing structure to a dataframe in spark using python.

```
df1=[['usr1',('itm1',2),('itm3',3)], ['usr2',('itm2',3), ('itm3',5),(itm22,6)]]
```

After converting, my dataframe should look like the following:

```
       usr1  usr2
itm1    2.0   NaN
itm2    NaN   3.0
itm22   NaN   6.0
itm3    3.0   5.0
```

I was initially thinking of coverting the above RDD structure to the following:

```
df1={'usr1': {'itm1': 2, 'itm3': 3}, 'usr2': {'itm2': 3, 'itm3': 5, 'itm22':6}}
```

Then use python's pandas module `pand=pd.DataFrame(dat2)` and then convert pandas dataframe back to a spark dataframe using `spark_df = context.createDataFrame(pand)`. However, I beleive, by doing this, I am converting an RDD to a non-RDD object and then converting back to RDD, which is not correct. Can some please help me out with this problem?

Comment: How is that different, excluding column choice,  [from your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37514344/1560062)?

Comment: please note that in my previous question I was more concerned with handling duplicate "itms" for the same user ( see  "if there is one more count field like in the above tuple i.e., ('itm1',3) how to incorporate (or add) this value 3 into the final result of the contingency table (or entity-item matrix)". Since the answer that was given is still not clear (atleast from my perspective), if I am able to get a solution for this question, I can close down on the answer to my previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data like this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ['usr1',('itm1',2),('itm3',3)], ['usr2',('itm2',3), ('itm3',5),('itm22',6)]
])
```

flatten the records:

```
def to_record(kvs):
    user, *vs = kvs  # For Python 2.x use standard indexing / splicing
    for item, value in vs:
        yield user, item, value

records = rdd.flatMap(to_record)
```

convert to `DataFrame`:

```
df = records.toDF(["user", "item", "value"])
```

pivot:

```
result = df.groupBy("item").pivot("user").sum()

result.show()
## +-----+----+----+
## | item|usr1|usr2|
## +-----+----+----+
## | itm1|   2|null|
## | itm2|null|   3|
## | itm3|   3|   5|
## |itm22|null|   6|
## +-----+----+----+
```

**Note**: Spark `DataFrames` are designed to handle long and relatively thin data. If you want to generate wide contingency table, `DataFrames` won't be useful, especially if data is dense and you want to keep separate column per feature.

Comment: perfect thanks a lot! and thanks for that extra bit of information too.