# Transpose column to row with Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pivot, transpose

I'm trying to transpose some columns of my table to row. 
I'm using Python and Spark 1.5.0. Here is my initial table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|  A  |col_1|col_2|col_...|
+-----+-------------------+
|  1  |  0.0|  0.6|  ...  |
|  2  |  0.6|  0.7|  ...  |
|  3  |  0.5|  0.9|  ...  |
|  ...|  ...|  ...|  ...  |
```

I would like to have somthing like this:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+
|  A  | col_id | col_value |
+-----+--------+-----------+
|  1  |   col_1|        0.0|
|  1  |   col_2|        0.6|   
|  ...|     ...|        ...|    
|  2  |   col_1|        0.6|
|  2  |   col_2|        0.7| 
|  ...|     ...|        ...|  
|  3  |   col_1|        0.5|
|  3  |   col_2|        0.9|
|  ...|     ...|        ...|
```

Does someone know haw I can do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: See also [unpivot in spark-sql/pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42465568/9613318)  and [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41670103/9613318)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.4**

You can use built-in `melt` method. With Python:

```py
df.melt(
    ids=["A"], values=["col_1", "col_2"],
    variableColumnName="key", valueColumnName="val"
)
```

with Scala

```scala
df.melt(Array($"A"), Array($"col_1", $"col_2"), "key", "val")
```

**Spark < 3.4**

It is relatively simple to do with basic Spark SQL functions.

**Python**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, struct, lit

df = sc.parallelize([(1, 0.0, 0.6), (1, 0.6, 0.7)]).toDF(["A", "col_1", "col_2"])

def to_long(df, by):

    # Filter dtypes and split into column names and type description
    cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in by))
    # Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns
    assert len(set(dtypes)) == 1, "All columns have to be of the same type"

    # Create and explode an array of (column_name, column_value) structs
    kvs = explode(array([
      struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val")) for c in cols
    ])).alias("kvs")

    return df.select(by + [kvs]).select(by + ["kvs.key", "kvs.val"])

to_long(df, ["A"])
```

**Scala**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, col, explode, lit, struct}

val df = Seq((1, 0.0, 0.6), (1, 0.6, 0.7)).toDF("A", "col_1", "col_2")

def toLong(df: DataFrame, by: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
  val (cols, types) = df.dtypes.filter{ case (c, _) => !by.contains(c)}.unzip
  require(types.distinct.size == 1, s"${types.distinct.toString}.length != 1")      

  val kvs = explode(array(
    cols.map(c => struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val"))): _*
  ))
  
  val byExprs = by.map(col(_))

  df
    .select(byExprs :+ kvs.alias("_kvs"): _*)
    .select(byExprs ++ Seq($"_kvs.key", $"_kvs.val"): _*)
}

toLong(df, Seq("A"))
```

Comment: I don't think that's "relatively" simple :)

Comment: i get the error `AssertionError: All columns have to be of the same type`

Comment: How to write this in Java ?

Comment: How to do the opposite of it. How to make the 1st dataframe from the 2nd dataframe?

Comment: @ShekharKoirala it is because the columns in your dataframe are of different datatypes, it is clearly mentioned in the function code.

Comment: Is it still the best approach even with latest Spark version? Wondering if UDF would address it better.

Answer (score 14):

One way to solve with `pyspark sql` using functions `create_map` and `explode`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
#Use `create_map` to create the map of columns with constant 
df = df.withColumn('mapCol', \
                    func.create_map(func.lit('col_1'),df.col_1,
                                    func.lit('col_2'),df.col_2,
                                    func.lit('col_3'),df.col_3
                                   ) 
                  )
#Use explode function to explode the map 
res = df.select('*',func.explode(df.mapCol).alias('col_id','col_value'))
res.show()
```

Comment: Nice answer, Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: Can you let me know how to convert this to all the columns without hardcoding column names .. I tried this but getting error
```
df = df.withColumn(
        'mapCol', F.create_map(
            *[F.struct(F.lit(x), F.col(x)) for x in df.columns]
        )
    )

Error: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'map(struct('col_name', 'col_name'))' due to data type mismatch: map expects a positive even number of arguments.;
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use the **stack** function:

for example:

```
df.selectExpr("stack(2, 'col_1', col_1, 'col_2', col_2) as (key, value)")
```

where:

- 2 is the number of columns to stack (col_1 and col_2)
- 'col_1' is a string for the key
- col_1 is the column from which to take the values

if you have several columns, you could build the whole **stack** string iterating the column names and pass that to **selectExpr**

Comment: df.selectExpr('column_names_to_keep', 'column_names_to_keep', "stack(2, 'col_1', col_1, 'col_2', col_2) as (key, value)")

Comment: I am using this function, but running into columns with different data types. I.e. some are string, and some decimal. How do I convert decimal type to string using stack?

Answer (score 7):

The Spark local linear algebra libraries are presently very weak: and they do not include basic operations as the above.

There is a JIRA for fixing this for Spark 2.1 - but that will not help you *today*.

Something to consider: performing a transpose will likely require completely shuffling the data.

For now you will need to write RDD code directly. I have written `transpose` in scala - but not in python.  Here is the `scala` version:

```
 def transpose(mat: DMatrix) = {
    val nCols = mat(0).length
    val matT = mat
      .flatten
      .zipWithIndex
      .groupBy {
      _._2 % nCols
    }
      .toSeq.sortBy {
      _._1
    }
      .map(_._2)
      .map(_.map(_._1))
      .toArray
    matT
  }
```

So you can convert that to python for your use. I do not have bandwidth to write/test that at this particular moment: let me know if you were unable to do that conversion.

At the least - the following are readily converted to `python`.

- `zipWithIndex` --> `enumerate()` (python equivalent - credit to @zero323)
- `map` --> `[someOperation(x) for x in ..]`
- `groupBy` --> `itertools.groupBy()`

Here is the implementation for `flatten` which does not have a python equivalent:

```
  def flatten(L):
        for item in L:
            try:
                for i in flatten(item):
                    yield i
            except TypeError:
                yield item
```

So you should be able to put those together for a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know scala but I will try to understand your code. I will keep you informed.

Comment: @Raouf  The code above all has equivalents in python. If you know python well there should not be an issue. I showed the `flatten` which is the only one missing from python. Let me know ;)

Comment: `zipWithIndex` --> `enumerate()` (Python equivalent)?

Comment: @zero323 Good eyes!  I am going to upvote your v nice answer btw.

Comment: Thanks. It is slightly more verbose but doesn't move data so much.

Comment: "does not move data as much".  V likely true. My code is a series of shuffle-inducing transformations.  Will look more closely at your approach from the "retain the present partitioning scheme" perspective. Update: yes you have fewer xform steps - so faster as well as likely easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Use flatmap. Something like below should work

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def rowExpander(row):
    rowDict = row.asDict()
    valA = rowDict.pop('A')
    for k in rowDict:
        yield Row(**{'A': valA , 'colID': k, 'colValue': row[k]})

newDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd.flatMap(rowExpander))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not work. Here is the error message I get: **TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str**

Answer (score 1):

I took the Scala answer that @javadba wrote and created a Python version for transposing all columns in a `DataFrame`. This might be a bit different from what OP was asking...

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


def _sort_transpose_tuple(tup):
    x, y = tup
    return x, tuple(zip(*sorted(y, key=lambda v_k: v_k[1], reverse=False)))[0]


def transpose(X):
    """Transpose a PySpark DataFrame.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : PySpark ``DataFrame``
        The ``DataFrame`` that should be tranposed.
    """
    # validate
    if not isinstance(X, DataFrame):
        raise TypeError('X should be a DataFrame, not a %s' 
                        % type(X))

    cols = X.columns
    n_features = len(cols)

    # Sorry for this unreadability...
    return X.rdd.flatMap( # make into an RDD
        lambda xs: chain(xs)).zipWithIndex().groupBy( # zip index
        lambda val_idx: val_idx[1] % n_features).sortBy( # group by index % n_features as key
        lambda grp_res: grp_res[0]).map( # sort by index % n_features key
        lambda grp_res: _sort_transpose_tuple(grp_res)).map( # maintain order
        lambda key_col: key_col[1]).toDF() # return to DF
```

For example:

```
>>> X = sc.parallelize([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]).toDF()
>>> X.show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+

>>> transpose(X).show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  4|  7|
|  2|  5|  8|
|  3|  6|  9|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

A very handy way to implement:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def rowExpander(row):
    rowDict = row.asDict()
    valA = rowDict.pop('A')
    for k in rowDict:
        yield Row(**{'A': valA , 'colID' : k, 'colValue' : row[k]})

    newDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd.flatMap(rowExpander)
```

Answer (score 0):

To transpose Dataframe in `pySpark`, I use `pivot` over the temporary created column, which I drop at the end of the operation.

Say, we have a table like this. What we wanna do is to find all users over each `listed_days_bin` value.

```
+------------------+-------------+
|  listed_days_bin | users_count | 
+------------------+-------------+
|1                 |            5| 
|0                 |            2|
|0                 |            1| 
|1                 |            3|  
|1                 |            4| 
|2                 |            5| 
|2                 |            7|  
|2                 |            2|  
|1                 |            1|
+------------------+-------------+
```

Create new temp column - `'pvt_value'`, aggregate over it and pivot results

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


agg_df = df.withColumn('pvt_value', lit(1))\
        .groupby('pvt_value')\
        .pivot('listed_days_bin')\
        .agg(F.sum('users_count')).drop('pvt_value')
```

New Dataframe should look like:

```
+----+---+---+
|  0 | 1 | 2 | # Columns 
+----+---+---+
|   3| 13| 14| # Users over the bin
+----+---+---+
```

Comment: This is the other way around though from the OPs question

Comment: The question is to "un-pivot", your answer shows how to pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I found PySpark to be too complicated to transpose so I just convert my dataframe to Pandas and use the transpose() method and convert the dataframe back to PySpark if required.

```
dfOutput = spark.createDataFrame(dfPySpark.toPandas().transpose())
dfOutput.display()
```