# How to melt Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, melt

Is there an equivalent of Pandas Melt function in Apache Spark in PySpark or at least in Scala?

I was running a sample dataset till now in Python and now I want to use Spark for the entire dataset.

Comment: See also [unpivot in spark-sql/pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42465568/9613318) and [Transpose column to row with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37864222/9613318)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.4**

In Spark 3.4 or later you can use built-in `melt` method

```py
(sdf
    .melt(
        ids=['A'], values=['B', 'C'], 
        variableColumnName="variable", 
        valueColumnName="value")
    .show())
```

```
+---+--------+-----+
|  A|variable|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       B|    1|
|  a|       C|    2|
|  b|       B|    3|
|  b|       C|    4|
|  c|       B|    5|
|  c|       C|    6|
+---+--------+-----+
```

This method is available across all APIs so could be used in Scala

```scala
sdf.melt(Array($"A"), Array($"B", $"C"), "variable", "value")
```

or SQL

```sql
SELECT * FROM sdf UNPIVOT (val FOR col in (col_1, col_2))
```

**Spark 3.2** (Python only, requires Pandas and pyarrow)

```py
(sdf
    .to_koalas()
    .melt(id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B', 'C'])
    .to_spark()
    .show())
```

```
+---+--------+-----+
|  A|variable|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       B|    1|
|  a|       C|    2|
|  b|       B|    3|
|  b|       C|    4|
|  c|       B|    5|
|  c|       C|    6|
+---+--------+-----+
```

**Spark < 3.2**

There is no built-in function (if you work with SQL and Hive support enabled you can use [`stack` function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-stack(values)), but it is not exposed in Spark and has no native implementation) but it is trivial to roll your own. Required imports:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, lit, struct
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from typing import Iterable
```

Example implementation:

```
def melt(
        df: DataFrame, 
        id_vars: Iterable[str], value_vars: Iterable[str], 
        var_name: str="variable", value_name: str="value") -> DataFrame:
    """Convert :class:`DataFrame` from wide to long format."""

    # Create array<struct<variable: str, value: ...>>
    _vars_and_vals = array(*(
        struct(lit(c).alias(var_name), col(c).alias(value_name)) 
        for c in value_vars))

    # Add to the DataFrame and explode
    _tmp = df.withColumn("_vars_and_vals", explode(_vars_and_vals))

    cols = id_vars + [
            col("_vars_and_vals")[x].alias(x) for x in [var_name, value_name]]
    return _tmp.select(*cols)
```

And some tests (based on [Pandas doctests](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)):

```
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
                   'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
                   'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})

pd.melt(pdf, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B', 'C'])
```

```
   A variable  value
0  a        B      1
1  b        B      3
2  c        B      5
3  a        C      2
4  b        C      4
5  c        C      6
```

```py
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
melt(sdf, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B', 'C']).show()
```

```
+---+--------+-----+
|  A|variable|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       B|    1|
|  a|       C|    2|
|  b|       B|    3|
|  b|       C|    4|
|  c|       B|    5|
|  c|       C|    6|
+---+--------+-----+
```

Note: For use with legacy Python versions remove type annotations.

Related:

- [R SparkR - equivalent to melt function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52782554/6910411)
- [Gather in sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50465390/6910411)

Comment: Your code adds back ticks to the column names and then it fails on `withColumn` call. More ref available here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781796/how-to-remove-automatically-added-back-ticks-while-using-explode-in-pyspark)

Comment: How is this benchmarked in comparison to the `stack` option? as in: `df.selectExpr('col1', 'stack(2, "col2", col2, "col3", col3) as (cols, values)')`

Comment: This isn't a trivial answer. This is a genius one!

Comment: Amazing answer. I've used this function many times without any problem.

Comment: This is truly amazing. `explode` works with columns containing lists but creating the array *"_vars_and_vals"* as a key-value pair array of structure and then using it in a withColumn statement within explode is a very interesting behavior. What @BICube said!

Comment: Spark 3.4 isn't release yet (https://is.spark.released.info/) as of writing this comment. Is there any official announcement that you can point me to?

Answer (score 35):

Came across this question in my search for an implementation of `melt` in Spark for Scala.

Posting my Scala port in case someone also stumbles upon this.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame}
/** Extends the [[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]] class
 *
 *  @param df the data frame to melt
 */
implicit class DataFrameFunctions(df: DataFrame) {

    /** Convert [[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]] from wide to long format.
     * 
     *  melt is (kind of) the inverse of pivot
     *  melt is currently (02/2017) not implemented in spark
     *
     *  @see reshape packe in R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape/index.html)
     *  @see this is a scala adaptation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/pandas-melt-function-in-apache-spark
     *  
     *  @todo method overloading for simple calling
     *
     *  @param id_vars the columns to preserve
     *  @param value_vars the columns to melt
     *  @param var_name the name for the column holding the melted columns names
     *  @param value_name the name for the column holding the values of the melted columns
     *
     */

    def melt(
            id_vars: Seq[String], value_vars: Seq[String], 
            var_name: String = "variable", value_name: String = "value") : DataFrame = {

        // Create array<struct<variable: str, value: ...>>
        val _vars_and_vals = array((for (c <- value_vars) yield { struct(lit(c).alias(var_name), col(c).alias(value_name)) }): _*)

        // Add to the DataFrame and explode
        val _tmp = df.withColumn("_vars_and_vals", explode(_vars_and_vals))

        val cols = id_vars.map(col _) ++ { for (x <- List(var_name, value_name)) yield { col("_vars_and_vals")(x).alias(x) }}

        return _tmp.select(cols: _*)

    }
}
```

Since I'm am not that advanced considering `Scala`, I'm sure there is room for improvement.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Your code is okay but I would advice replace `for-yield` constructions just to `map` functions, for-example:  `{ for (x <- List(var_name, value_name)) yield { col("_vars_and_vals")(x).alias(x) }}` is the same as `List(var_name, value_name).map(x => col("_vars_and_vals")(x).alias(x))`
and `for (c <- value_vars) yield { struct(lit(c).alias(var_name), col(c).alias(value_name)) }` can be written so: `value_vars.map(c => struct(lit(c).alias(var_name), col(c).alias(value_name)))`. for-yield is more general thing in **scala**  than for-comprehension in **python**.

Answer (score 8):

Voted for user6910411's answer. It works as expected, however, it cannot handle None values well. thus I refactored his melt function to the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from typing import Iterable 
from itertools import chain

def melt(
        df: DataFrame, 
        id_vars: Iterable[str], value_vars: Iterable[str], 
        var_name: str="variable", value_name: str="value") -> DataFrame:
    """Convert :class:`DataFrame` from wide to long format."""

    # Create map<key: value>
    _vars_and_vals = create_map(
        list(chain.from_iterable([
            [lit(c), col(c)] for c in value_vars]
        ))
    )

    _tmp = df.select(*id_vars, explode(_vars_and_vals)) \
        .withColumnRenamed('key', var_name) \
        .withColumnRenamed('value', value_name)

    return _tmp
```

Test is with the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
                   'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
                   'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6},
                   'D': {1: 7, 2: 9}})

pd.melt(pdf, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B', 'C', 'D'])

A   variable    value
0   a   B   1.0
1   b   B   3.0
2   c   B   5.0
3   a   C   2.0
4   b   C   4.0
5   c   C   6.0
6   a   D   NaN
7   b   D   7.0
8   c   D   9.0
```

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
melt(sdf, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B', 'C', 'D']).show()
+---+--------+-----+
|  A|variable|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       B|  1.0|
|  a|       C|  2.0|
|  a|       D|  NaN|
|  b|       B|  3.0|
|  b|       C|  4.0|
|  b|       D|  7.0|
|  c|       B|  5.0|
|  c|       C|  6.0|
|  c|       D|  9.0|
+---+--------+-----+
```

Comment: How would this work if I am trying to pass in a list i.e 'someColumns' for the value_vars?

I'm getting an 'Unsupported literal type class' error.

Comment: It works for me perfectly, nice job! @Budyn: what exactly are you passing into the value_vars parameter? I pass a list of strings (of column names), like this: `df_long = melt(df_wide, id_vars=['id', 'date'], value_vars=['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'])`

Answer (score 4):

## UPD

Finally i've found most effective implementation for me. It uses all resources for cluster in my yarn configuration.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
def melt(df):
    sp = df.columns[1:]
    return (df
            .rdd
            .map(lambda x: [str(x[0]), [(str(i[0]), 
                                         float(i[1] if i[1] else 0)) for i in zip(sp, x[1:])]], 
                 preservesPartitioning = True)
            .toDF()
            .withColumn('_2', explode('_2'))
            .rdd.map(lambda x: [str(x[0]), 
                                str(x[1][0]), 
                                float(x[1][1] if x[1][1] else 0)], 
                     preservesPartitioning = True)
            .toDF()
            )
```

---

For very wide dataframe I've got performance decreasing at _vars_and_vals generation from user6910411 answer.

It was useful to implement melting via selectExpr

```
columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
pd_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7,9,8], [7,8,9,1,2,4], [8,3,9,8,7,4]], columns=columns)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
|  4|  5|  6|  7|  9|  8|
|  7|  8|  9|  1|  2|  4|
|  8|  3|  9|  8|  7|  4|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

cols = df.columns[1:]
df.selectExpr('a', "stack({}, {})".format(len(cols), ', '.join(("'{}', {}".format(i, i) for i in cols))))
+---+----+----+
|  a|col0|col1|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   b|   2|
|  1|   c|   3|
|  1|   d|   4|
|  1|   e|   5|
|  1|   f|   6|
|  4|   b|   5|
|  4|   c|   6|
|  4|   d|   7|
|  4|   e|   9|
|  4|   f|   8|
|  7|   b|   8|
|  7|   c|   9|
...
```

Comment: I am having some type mismatch **cannot resolve.. due to data type mismatch: Argument 2 (DoubleType) != Argument 6 (LongType); line 1 pos 0;** . Testing shows that it seem stack imply the type of your col1 based on the first few elements of col0 . When let's say values for d or f of col0 come in, type mismatch. How would you solve that ? I am trying _stack({}, {})".format(len(cols), ', '.join(("'{}', cast({} as bigint)"..._ which seems to work, but not sure if it's the correct and efficient way. I am having performance issue when stacking hundreds of columns so efficiency is important.

Comment: @Kenny I've never met such problem in this case. But you solution sounds logical. Also you can try my solution from update.

Answer (score -1):

Use list comprehension to create struct column of column names and col values and explode the new column using the magic inline. Code below;

```
    melted_df=(df.withColumn(
                 #Create struct of column names and corresponding values
                'tab',F.array(*[F.struct(lit(x).alias('var'),F.col(x).alias('val'))for x in df.columns if x!='A'] ))
                 #Explode the column
                 .selectExpr('A',"inline(tab)")
          
)
  
melted_df.show()

+---+---+---+
|  A|var|val|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  B|  1|
|  a|  C|  2|
|  b|  B|  3|
|  b|  C|  4|
|  c|  B|  5|
|  c|  C|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score -1):

`1)` Copy & paste
`2)` Change the first 2 variables

```py
to_melt = {'latin', 'greek', 'chinese'}
new_names = ['lang', 'letter']

melt_str = ','.join([f"'{c}', `{c}`" for c in to_melt])
df = df.select(
    *(set(df.columns) - to_melt),
    F.expr(f"stack({len(to_melt)}, {melt_str}) ({','.join(new_names)})")
)
```

`null` is created if some values contain null. To remove it, add this:

```py
.filter(f"!{new_names[1]} is null")
```

---

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(101, "A", "Σ", "西"), (102, "B", "Ω", "诶")], ['ID', 'latin', 'greek', 'chinese'])
df.show()
# +---+-----+-----+-------+
# | ID|latin|greek|chinese|
# +---+-----+-----+-------+
# |101|    A|    Σ|     西|
# |102|    B|    Ω|     诶|
# +---+-----+-----+-------+

to_melt = {'latin', 'greek', 'chinese'}
new_names = ['lang', 'letter']

melt_str = ','.join([f"'{c}', `{c}`" for c in to_melt])
df = df.select(
    *(set(df.columns) - to_melt),
    F.expr(f"stack({len(to_melt)}, {melt_str}) ({','.join(new_names)})")
)

df.show()
# +---+-------+------+
# | ID|   lang|letter|
# +---+-------+------+
# |101|  latin|     A|
# |101|  greek|     Σ|
# |101|chinese|    西|
# |102|  latin|     B|
# |102|  greek|     Ω|
# |102|chinese|    诶|
# +---+-------+------+
```