# I want to convert columns to row in py spark dataframe without using pandas?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have already gone through the above answers and posted my concerns in comments, so please do not close this before answering my comments.

I went through some of the answers available but none was working

**Sample dataset:**

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry If I am being naive here, I am very new to PY spark and I tried replicating the first answer given on this query:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/pandas-melt-function-in-apache-spark#

But I have following doubts in above queries:

1. not able to import this 'from typing import Iterable '
error: No module named typing

2. where I have to give columns to be retained and columns to be melted down?

Comment: Also, I am getting following error for 'df: DataFrame'
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 if I run the definition part of the code.