# Pyspark: reduceByKey multiple columns but independently

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My data consists of multiple columns and it looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to group the data for each column separately and count number of occurrences of each element, which I can achieve by doing this:

```
df.groupBy("Col-1").count() 

df.groupBy("Col-2").count()

df.groupBy("Col-n").count()
```

However, if there are 1000 of columns, it my be time consuming. So I was trying to find the another way to do it:

At the moment what I have done so far:

```
def mapFxn1(x):
    vals=[1] * len(x)
    c=tuple(zip(list(x), vals))
    return c

df_map=df.rdd.map(lambda x: mapFxn1(x))
```

mapFxn1 takes each row and transforms it into tuple of tuples: so basically row one would look like this: ((10, 1), (2, 1), (x, 1))

I am just wondering how one can used reduceByKey on df_map with the lambda x,y: x + y in order to achieve the grouping on each of columns and counting the occurrences of elements in each of the columns in single step.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cube`:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(3, 2), (2, 1), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 1)]
).toDF("col1", "col2")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql("""SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) 
             FROM df GROUP BY col1, col2 GROUPING SETS(col1, col2)"""
).show()

# +----+----+--------+
# |col1|col2|count(1)|
# +----+----+--------+
# |null|   9|       1|
# |   3|null|       3|
# |null|   1|       2|
# |null|   2|       1|
# |   2|null|       1|
# |null|   8|       1|
# |   4|null|       1|
# +----+----+--------+
```

With [`melt`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41670103/8371915):

```py
melt(df, [], df.columns).groupBy("variable", "value").count().show()

# +--------+-----+-----+
# |variable|value|count|
# +--------+-----+-----+
# |    col2|    8|    1|
# |    col1|    3|    3|
# |    col2|    2|    1|
# |    col1|    2|    1|
# |    col2|    9|    1|
# |    col1|    4|    1|
# |    col2|    1|    2|
# +--------+-----+-----+
```

With `reduceByKey`

```py
from operator import add

counts = (df.rdd
   .flatMap(lambda x: x.asDict().items())
   .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
   .reduceByKey(add))

counts.toLocalIterator():
    print(x)
#     
# (('col1', 2), 1)
# (('col2', 8), 1)
# (('col2', 1), 2)
# (('col2', 9), 1)
# (('col1', 4), 1)
# (('col1', 3), 3)
# (('col2', 2), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. It seems to work. I was particularly interested in reduceByKey approach. Although it's working as expected. The performance is the issue. I have 50M rows and 60 columns. It took almost more than 10 minutes on my 8 core machine. However, if I do same task with python and numpy ( simply passing through the file 10K lines at time and applying the numpy hist function and then updating the counts) it took less than 3 minutes on single core. Is this normal behavior?