# PySpark: Should we update a dataframe iteratively?

Tags: python, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark

My question has two parts to it.
First one is to understand the way Spark works and the second one is on optimization.

I have a spark dataframe which has multiple categorical variables. For each of these categorical variables I am adding a new column wherein each row is the frequency of the corresponding level.

For example

```
Date_Built  Square_Footage  Num_Beds    Num_Baths   State   Price     Freq_State
01/01/1920  1700            3           2           NY      700000    4500
```

Here for `State` (a categorical variable), I am adding a new variable `Freq_State`. The level `NY` appears `4500` times in the dataset so this row gets `4500` in the `Freq_State` column.

I have multiple such columns where I am adding a column bearing frequency of corresponding levels.

This is the code I am using for achieving this

```
def calculate_freq(df, categorical_cols):
    for each_cat_col in categorical_cols:
        _freq = df.select(each_cat_col).groupBy(each_cat_col).count()
        df = df.join(_freq, each_cat_col, "inner")
    return df
```

**Part 1**

Here, as you can see, I am updating the dataframe in the `for` loop. Is this way of updating a dataframe advisable when I'm running this code on a cluster? I wouldn't have been concerned about this if it was a pandas dataframe. But I am not certain when the context changes to spark.

Also, would it make a difference if I was simply running the above process in a loop and not inside a function?

**Part 2**

Is there a more optimized way to do this? Here I am joining each time I enter a loop? Can this be avoided

Comment: Why are you joining back on `df`? To have the count repeated on each record?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele, yes. For every row where State equals NY, 4500 will be in that row.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more optimized way to do this?

What are possible alternatives?

1. You could use Window functions

   ```
   def calculate_freq(df, categorical_cols):
       for cat_col in categorical_cols:
           w = Window.partitionBy(cat_col)
           df = df.withColumn("{}_freq".format(each_cat_col), count("*").over(w))
       return df
   ```

   Should you? No. Unlike `join` it will always require a full shuffle of the non-aggregated `DataFrame`.
2. You could [`melt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/pandas-melt-function-in-apache-spark/41673644#41673644) and use single local object (this requires all categorical columns to be of the same type):

   ```
   from itertools import groupby

   for c in categorical_cols:
        df = df.withColumn(c, df[c].cast("string"))


   rows = (melt(df, id_vars=[], value_vars=categorical_cols)
           .groupBy("variable", "value").count().collect())

   mapping = {k: {x.value: x["count"] for x in v} 
             for k, v in groupby(sorted(rows), lambda x: x.variable)}
   ```

   And use `udf` to add values:

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

   def get_count(mapping_c):
       @udf("bigint")
       def _(x):
           return mapping_c.get(x)
       return _


   for c in categorical_cols:
       df = df.withColumn("{}_freq".format(c), get_count(mapping[c])(c))
   ```

   Should you? Maybe. Unlike iterative join it requires only a single action to compute all statistics. If result is small (expected with categorical variables) you can get a moderate performance boost.
3. Add `broadcast` hint.

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

   def calculate_freq(df, categorical_cols):
       for each_cat_col in categorical_cols:
           _freq = df.select(each_cat_col).groupBy(each_cat_col).count()
       df = df.join(broadcast(_freq), each_cat_col, "inner")
       return df
   ```

   Spark should broadcast automatically, so it shouldn't change a thing, but it is always better to help planner.

> Also, would it make a difference if I was simply running the above process in a loop and not inside a function?

Ignoring code maintainability and testability it would not.