# Generic Solution Of Transpose dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

How i can transpose the dataframe in pyspark.

My Table is shown as below -

```
|two|0.6|1.2|1.7|1.5|1.4|2.0|
|one|0.3|1.2|1.3|1.5|1.4|1.0|
```

i want to transpose to

```
+---+---+
|two|one|
+---+---+
|0.6|0.3|
|1.2|1.2|
|1.7|1.3|
|1.5|1.5|
|1.4|1.4|
|2.0|1.0|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Please reformat your data tables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe does this help?