# How to unpivot Spark DataFrame without hardcoding column names in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, unpivot

Assume you have

```
val df = Seq(("Jack", 91, 86), ("Mike", 79, 85), ("Julia", 93, 70)).toDF("Name", "Maths", "Art")
```

which gives:

```
+-----+-----+---+
| Name|Maths|Art|
+-----+-----+---+
| Jack|   91| 86|
| Mike|   79| 85|
|Julia|   93| 70|
+-----+-----+---+
```

Now you want to unpivot it by:

```
df.select($"Name", expr("stack(2, 'Maths', Maths, 'Art', Art) as (Subject, Score)"))
```

which gives:

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| Name|Subject|Score|
+-----+-------+-----+
| Jack|  Maths|   91|
| Jack|    Art|   86|
| Mike|  Maths|   79|
| Mike|    Art|   85|
|Julia|  Maths|   93|
|Julia|    Art|   70|
+-----+-------+-----+
```

So far so godd! Now, what if you don't know the list of column names? What if the list of column names is long or it can change? How can we avoid hardcoding the column names stupidly like that?

Or even something like this is also good:

```
// fake code
df.select($"Name", unpivot(df.columns.diff("Name")) as ("Subject", "Score"))
```

Why don't we have api like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @user10938362 HI, I saw the answer for Scala usibg melt, but it still requires specifying column names manually

Comment: @user10938362 true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works quite well indeed:

```
def melt(preserves: Seq[String], toMelt: Seq[String], column: String = "variable", row: String = "value", df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    val _vars_and_vals = array((for (c <- toMelt) yield { struct(lit(c).alias(column), col(c).alias(row)) }): _*)
    val _tmp = df.withColumn("_vars_and_vals", explode(_vars_and_vals))
    val cols = preserves.map(col _) ++ { for (x <- List(column, row)) yield { col("_vars_and_vals")(x).alias(x) }}
    _tmp.select(cols: _*)
}
```

Source: [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)
Thanks to @user10938362

Answer (score 1):

By making use of **`.mkString`** multi delimiter we can create expression and use it in expr.

Example:

```
df.show()
//+-----+-----+---+
//| Name|Maths|Art|
//+-----+-----+---+
//| Jack|   91| 86|
//| Mike|   79| 85|
//|Julia|   93| 70|
//+-----+-----+---+

//filtering required cols
val cols=df.columns.filter(_.toLowerCase != "name")

//defining alias cols string
val alias_cols="Subject,Score"

//mkString with 3 seperators
val stack_exp=cols.map(x => s"""'${x}',${x}""").mkString(s"stack(${cols.size},",",",s""") as (${alias_cols})""")

df.select($"Name", expr(s"""${stack_exp}""")).show()
//+-----+-------+-----+
//| Name|Subject|Score|
//+-----+-------+-----+
//| Jack|  Maths|   91|
//| Jack|    Art|   86|
//| Mike|  Maths|   79|
//| Mike|    Art|   85|
//|Julia|  Maths|   93|
//|Julia|    Art|   70|
//+-----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if the column names contains space, it won't work