# pyspark dataframe transpose issue

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hive, pivot-table, transpose

I have a following input dataframe with the respective columns:

```
dim1,dim2,tran_clmn,input1,input2
101,201,Y1,1,2
102,202,Y2,2,3
103,203,Y3,3,4
104,204,Y4,4,5
105,205,Y5,5,6
```

I need to transpose the input data to the below transposed output based on column **tran_clmn**

```
dim1,dim2,new_trn_clm,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5
101,201,input1,1,,,,
101,201,input2,2,,,,
102,202,input1,,2,,,
102,202,input2,,3,,,
103,203,input1,,,3,,
103,203,input2,,,4,,
104,204,input1,,,,4,
104,204,input2,,,,5,
105,205,input1,,,,,5
105,205,input2,,,,,6
```

how to achieve this kind of scenario? there is no option of aggregation. could it be done and get the result using ***groupBy and pivot method***?

Answer (score 0):

Two years ago, I found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe) a function that performs that kind of transformation (wide to long). It has been very helpful to me: maybe it can for you too.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

def melt(df: DataFrame,
         id_vars: Iterable[str], value_vars: Iterable[str],
         var_name: str = "variable", value_name: str = "value"):
    """
    Convert :class:`DataFrame` from wide to long format.
    """
    # Create array<struct<variable: str, value: ...>>
    _vars_and_vals = psf.array(*(
        psf.struct(psf.lit(c).alias(var_name), psf.col(c).alias(value_name))
        for c in value_vars))
    # Add to the DataFrame and explode
    _tmp = df.withColumn("_vars_and_vals", psf.explode(_vars_and_vals))
    cols = id_vars + [
        psf.col("_vars_and_vals")[x].alias(x) for x in [var_name, value_name]]
    return _tmp.select(*cols)
```

In your case, this could be something like that (untested) :

```py
melt(df, id_vars=['dim1','dim2'],
                       value_vars=[input1','input2'],
                       var_name="tran_clmn", value_name="tran_clmn")
```