# Dynamically union data frames in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below in `pyspark`

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[
(100,"Single",0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.02),
(101,"Single",8.03,0.00,2.10,1.46,4.01,0.00,0.63),
(102,"Single",0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.02),
(100,"STACK",10.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.02),
(101,"Single",0.00,0.00,13.36,125.90,417.93,0.00,20.91),
(102,"PLUS",188.67,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
(100,"STACK",0.00,0.00,1.81,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
(101,"STACK",0.00,3.34,-0.01,53.97,43.26,0.00,5.64),
(102,"STACK",417.93,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00)
], 
("MERCHANT_ID","RATE", "INCOME_PDR" , "MULTI_PDR" , "TRANS_FEE_INCOME" , "PDR_MARGIN" , "INTER_CHANGE" , "TOTAL_MULTI_PDR" , "VOLUME_INC_MULTI"))
```

df.show()

```
+-----------+------+----------+---------+----------------+----------+------------+---------------+----------------+
|MERCHANT_ID|  RATE|INCOME_PDR|MULTI_PDR|TRANS_FEE_INCOME|PDR_MARGIN|INTER_CHANGE|TOTAL_MULTI_PDR|VOLUME_INC_MULTI|
+-----------+------+----------+---------+----------------+----------+------------+---------------+----------------+
|        100|Single|       0.0|      0.0|             0.0|       0.0|         0.0|            0.0|            0.02|
|        101|Single|      8.03|      0.0|             2.1|      1.46|        4.01|            0.0|            0.63|
|        102|Single|       0.0|      0.0|             0.0|       0.0|         0.0|            0.0|            0.02|
|        100| STACK|      10.0|      0.0|             0.0|       0.0|         0.0|            0.0|            0.02|
|        101|Single|       0.0|      0.0|           13.36|     125.9|      417.93|            0.0|           20.91|
|        102|  PLUS|    188.67|      0.0|             0.0|       0.0|         0.0|            0.0|             0.0|
|        100| STACK|       0.0|      0.0|            1.81|       0.0|         0.0|            0.0|             0.0|
|        101| STACK|       0.0|     3.34|           -0.01|     53.97|       43.26|            0.0|            5.64|
|        102| STACK|    417.93|      0.0|             0.0|       0.0|         0.0|            0.0|             0.0|
+-----------+------+----------+---------+----------------+----------+------------+---------------+----------------+
```

From this dataframe I would like to do a `sum of a column` and add a `new column` with `value` as `column_name of the which I am performing the sum`

I have done like below

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit


df1 = df.withColumn('ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', lit('INCOME_PDR'))\
.select(['MERCHANT_ID','RATE','INCOME_PDR','ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE'])\
.groupby('MERCHANT_ID','RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE')\
.sum('INCOME_PDR')\
.withColumnRenamed("sum(INCOME_PDR)", "AMOUNT_AUD")
```

df1.show()

```
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
|MERCHANT_ID|  RATE|ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE|AMOUNT_AUD|
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
|        100| STACK|           INCOME_PDR|      10.0|
|        101|Single|           INCOME_PDR|      8.03|
|        100|Single|           INCOME_PDR|       0.0|
|        102|  PLUS|           INCOME_PDR|    188.67|
|        102| STACK|           INCOME_PDR|    417.93|
|        101| STACK|           INCOME_PDR|       0.0|
|        102|Single|           INCOME_PDR|       0.0|
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
```

Same way for another column

```
df2 = df.withColumn('ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', lit('MULTI_PDR'))\
.select(['MERCHANT_ID','RATE','MULTI_PDR','ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE'])\
.groupby('MERCHANT_ID','RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE')\
.sum('MULTI_PDR')\
.withColumnRenamed("sum(MULTI_PDR)", "AMOUNT_AUD")
```

df2.show()

```
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
|MERCHANT_ID|  RATE|ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE|amount_aud|
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
|        102|  PLUS|            MULTI_PDR|       0.0|
|        102| STACK|            MULTI_PDR|       0.0|
|        101| STACK|            MULTI_PDR|      3.34|
|        102|Single|            MULTI_PDR|       0.0|
|        100| STACK|            MULTI_PDR|       0.0|
|        101|Single|            MULTI_PDR|       0.0|
|        100|Single|            MULTI_PDR|       0.0|
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
```

I want to do this for around 7 columns. I have done like below

3rd column

```
df3 = df.withColumn('ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', lit('TRANS_FEE_INCOME'))\
.select(['MERCHANT_ID','RATE','TRANS_FEE_INCOME','ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE'])\
.groupby('MERCHANT_ID','RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE')\
.sum('TRANS_FEE_INCOME')\
.withColumnRenamed("sum(TRANS_FEE_INCOME)", "AMOUNT_AUD")
```

column 4

```
df4 = df.withColumn('ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', lit('PDR_MARGIN'))\
.select(['MERCHANT_ID','RATE','PDR_MARGIN','ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE'])\
.groupby('MERCHANT_ID','RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE')\
.sum('PDR_MARGIN')\
.withColumnRenamed("sum(PDR_MARGIN)", "AMOUNT_AUD")
```

column 5

```
df5 = df.withColumn('ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', lit('INTER_CHANGE'))\
.select(['MERCHANT_ID','RATE','INTER_CHANGE','ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE'])\
.groupby('MERCHANT_ID','RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE')\
.sum('INTER_CHANGE')\
.withColumnRenamed("sum(INTER_CHANGE)", "AMOUNT_AUD")
```

column 6

```
df6 = df.withColumn('ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', lit('TOTAL_MULTI_PDR'))\
.select(['MERCHANT_ID','RATE','TOTAL_MULTI_PDR','ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE'])\
.groupby('MERCHANT_ID','RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE')\
.sum('TOTAL_MULTI_PDR')\
.withColumnRenamed("sum(TOTAL_MULTI_PDR)", "AMOUNT_AUD")
```

column 7

```
df7 = df.withColumn('ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', lit('VOLUME_INC_MULTI'))\
.select(['MERCHANT_ID','RATE','VOLUME_INC_MULTI','ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE'])\
.groupby('MERCHANT_ID','RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE')\
.sum('VOLUME_INC_MULTI')\
.withColumnRenamed("sum(VOLUME_INC_MULTI)", "AMOUNT_AUD")
```

Then I want to a union of all the 7 dataframes created. i have done like below

```
dfs =[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7]

df8 = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

I am able to get what is required. I would like know if there is a better approach than what I have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform your dataframe by using `flatMap`.

`flatMap` will iterate for each row with the lambda function. After that, `map` converts the row element to the `n-tuple` by iterating the column index `i` such as

- 1st: `row[0]` = value of `MERCHANT_ID` column
- 2nd: `row[1]` = value of `RATE` column
- 3rd: `cols[i]` = `i`-th element of `cols` where `i` from `(2, len(cols))`
- 4th: `row[i]` = value of `i`-th column where `i` from `(2, len(cols))`

```
|MERCHANT_ID|  RATE|INCOME_PDR|MULTI_PDR|TRANS_FEE_INCOME|PDR_MARGIN|INTER_CHANGE|TOTAL_MULTI_PDR|VOLUME_INC_MULTI|
+-----------+------+----------+---------+----------------+----------+------------+---------------+----------------+
|        100|Single|       0.0|      0.0|             0.0|       0.0|         0.0|            0.0|            0.02|
```

For example, the `4-tuple` is made from the first row as follows:

- `i=2`: `(100, 'Single', 'MULTI_PDR', 0.0)` <-- column for `i=2` is `MULTI_PDR`
- `i=3`: `(100, 'Single', 'TRANS_FEE_INCOME', 0.0)`  <-- column for `i=2` is `TRANS_FEE_INCOME`
- ...
- `i=len(cols)`: `(100, 'Single', 'VOLUME_INC_MULTI', 0.02)` <-- column for `i=len(cols)` is `VOLUME_INC_MULTI`

This is repeated for every row by `flatMap`

```py
#schema = df.schema

#df2 = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: map(lambda i: (row[0], row[1], schema[i].name, row[i]), range(2, len(schema)) )) \
#        .toDF(['MERCHANT_ID', 'RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', 'AMOUNT_AUD'])

cols = df.columns

df2 = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: map(lambda i: (row[0], row[1], cols[i], row[i]), range(2, len(cols)) )) \
        .toDF(['MERCHANT_ID', 'RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', 'AMOUNT_AUD'])

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2.groupBy('MERCHANT_ID', 'RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE') \
  .agg(f.sum('AMOUNT_AUD').alias('AMOUNT_AUD')) \
  .show(30, False)

+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
|MERCHANT_ID|RATE  |ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE|AMOUNT_AUD|
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
|102        |STACK |TRANS_FEE_INCOME     |0.0       |
|100        |STACK |PDR_MARGIN           |0.0       |
|100        |STACK |TOTAL_MULTI_PDR      |0.0       |
|102        |STACK |MULTI_PDR            |0.0       |
|102        |STACK |PDR_MARGIN           |0.0       |
|102        |STACK |INCOME_PDR           |417.93    |
|100        |Single|INCOME_PDR           |0.0       |
|100        |Single|PDR_MARGIN           |0.0       |
|101        |STACK |INTER_CHANGE         |43.26     |
|100        |Single|TOTAL_MULTI_PDR      |0.0       |
|100        |STACK |INTER_CHANGE         |0.0       |
|102        |STACK |VOLUME_INC_MULTI     |0.0       |
|102        |Single|TOTAL_MULTI_PDR      |0.0       |
|102        |PLUS  |MULTI_PDR            |0.0       |
|100        |Single|VOLUME_INC_MULTI     |0.02      |
|101        |Single|TOTAL_MULTI_PDR      |0.0       |
|100        |Single|INTER_CHANGE         |0.0       |
|101        |STACK |INCOME_PDR           |0.0       |
|101        |STACK |TOTAL_MULTI_PDR      |0.0       |
|102        |Single|INTER_CHANGE         |0.0       |
|102        |STACK |TOTAL_MULTI_PDR      |0.0       |
|100        |Single|TRANS_FEE_INCOME     |0.0       |
|102        |Single|INCOME_PDR           |0.0       |
|101        |STACK |PDR_MARGIN           |53.97     |
|101        |Single|INCOME_PDR           |8.03      |
|100        |STACK |TRANS_FEE_INCOME     |1.81      |
|102        |PLUS  |INTER_CHANGE         |0.0       |
|102        |PLUS  |TRANS_FEE_INCOME     |0.0       |
|101        |Single|INTER_CHANGE         |421.94    |
|102        |Single|VOLUME_INC_MULTI     |0.02      |
+-----------+------+---------------------+----------+
only showing top 30 rows
```

---

Here is another way to do only with the dataframe:

```
cols = df.columns

cols.remove('MERCHANT_ID')
cols.remove('RATE')

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('array', f.explode(f.arrays_zip(f.array(*map(lambda x: f.lit(x), cols)), f.array(*cols), ))) \
  .select('MERCHANT_ID', 'RATE', 'array.*') \
  .toDF('MERCHANT_ID', 'RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE', 'AMOUNT_AUD') \
  .groupBy('MERCHANT_ID', 'RATE', 'ACQUIRED_REVENUE_CODE') \
  .agg(f.sum('AMOUNT_AUD').alias('AMOUNT_AUD')) \
  .show(30, False)
```

where the method is referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511203/transpose-wide-dataframe-to-long-dataframe).

Comment: Using your first option I am able to get the desired result but for your `2` option I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arrays_zip'`

Comment: hm... your spark version looks lesser than 2.4.0 :( You should then use the first one only.

Comment: Yes I am using spark 2.3.2.

Comment: I am bit new to `spark` Can you please explain what is happening here `df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: map(lambda i: (row[0], row[1], schema[i].name, row[i]), range(2, len(schema)) ))`

Comment: I got what `df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: map(lambda i: (row[0], row[1], schema[i].name, row[i]), range(2, len(schema)) ))` is doing for every column after the range `2` column. It is pouplating the `column name` and `corresponding value`.

Comment: Quick question Here you are using `schema = df.schema` Can we use a list like you have done in the `2nd ` approach

Comment: For the last, yes. I will add.