# How to explode feature vector to a column in PySpark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, rdd

| id | texts | vector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [a, b, c] | (3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0]) |
| 1 | [a, b, c] | (3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0]) |

This is my above spark dataframe, I want to convert it to something like below -

| id | texts | list_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1.0 |
| 0 | b | 1.0 |
| 0 | c | 1.0 |
| 1 | a | 2.0 |
| 1 | b | 2.0 |
| 1 | c | 1.0 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import *



def to_array_(v):
 return v.toArray().tolist()
def to_vector_(v):
 return Vectors.dense(v)


to_array = udf(lambda z: to_array_(z),ArrayType(DoubleType())) #watch your return type
to_vector = udf(lambda z: to_vector_(z),VectorUDT()) # helper to make an example for your question.
getFeatureVector=udf(lambda v:v[2],VectorUDT()) #this should work on your Feature Vector, but I'm too lazy to contrive an example with Vectors of vectors.
getFeatureVectorExample=udf(lambda v:v[2],FloatType()) # This works for this example but gives you the general idea of how to access vectors.

schema = ["id","texts","vector"]
data = [
(0,['a', 'b', 'c'],[1.0,1.0,1.0]), #small cheat
(1,['a', 'b', 'c'],[2.0,2.0,1.0]),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame( data, schema )


df = df.withColumn("vector", to_vector(df.vector) ) #convert the array to a vector so I can prove this works
#DataFrame[id: bigint, texts: array<string>, vector: vector]
```

This may make you ask the question how do I access the element of vector to turn it into an array: (we use another udf that will translate for us.)

```
df.select(col('*'), getFeatureVectorExample( df.vector ) ).show()
+---+---------+-------------+----------------+
| id|    texts|       vector|<lambda>(vector)|
+---+---------+-------------+----------------+
|  0|[a, b, c]|[1.0,1.0,1.0]|             1.0|
|  1|[a, b, c]|[2.0,2.0,1.0]|             1.0|
+---+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

Ok so now we know how to get the element we're interest in so the rest of this example show how to convert a vector into an array, and then explode it.

```
df.withColumn( 'text', explode( df.texts) )\# I use with column as I'm lazy
.withColumn( 'feature', explode( to_array(df.vector) ) )\#can't have to explodes in 1 select so don't try to do that.
.drop('texts','vector')\#book keeping to clean up columns you don't want.
.show()
| id|text|feature|
+---+----+-------+
|  0|   a|    1.0|
|  0|   a|    1.0|
|  0|   a|    1.0|
|  0|   b|    1.0|
|  0|   b|    1.0|
|  0|   b|    1.0|
|  0|   c|    1.0|
|  0|   c|    1.0|
|  0|   c|    1.0|
|  1|   a|    2.0|
|  1|   a|    2.0|
|  1|   a|    1.0|
|  1|   b|    2.0|
|  1|   b|    2.0|
|  1|   b|    1.0|
|  1|   c|    2.0|
|  1|   c|    2.0|
|  1|   c|    1.0|
+---+----+-------+
```

To further clarify if you wish to access elements of a vector you can create a static function:

This function pulls the last element(2) of a vector out and returns it as a vector, but gives a hint to how to access other elements.
`getFeatureVector=udf(lambda v:v[2],VectorUDT())`
If the elements are different types you will need to write extra logic to handle it and the return type:
Here's an example to access the first(0) element of a vector and return it as a FloatType:
`getFeatureVectorExample=udf(lambda v:v[0],FloatType())`

You can of course combine these elements and return a more complex structure, that may suit your needs. I suggest returning them as a struct as you can use 'column_name.*' to turn the columns from the struct as rows or `struct_column.field_name` to access elements and return them as columns.  See [this example](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-structtype-and-structfield/) for how to build out the return type.

Further example using multitple elements in struct and turning them into a column

```
def structExample(v):
 return (
  float(v[0]),       
  float(v[0])
 )
getstructExample=udf(structExample,StructType([StructField( "flt", FloatType(), False), StructField( "array", FloatType() ) ]))

df.select(col('*'), getstructExample( df.vector ).alias("struct") ).select(col("struct.*")).show()
+---+-----+
|flt|array|
+---+-----+
|1.0|  1.0|
|2.0|  2.0|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for the help. While I understood how you are exploding an array to multiple rows, Can you please guide how to extract this value in a column -> (3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0]) into three columns with values -> 3, [0, 1, 2] and [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] ?

Comment: I added to my answer to help explain in more detail if I get time tonight I'll write up a better example.

Comment: Added a little more detailed example, this should give you everything you need.