# Efficient way to transpose and get years

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some transformation task.

I have to read a csv file with following data:

```
Name,Age,2020,2021,2022
ABCD,11,0.11,1,2.1
```

And the aforementioned dataframe has to be converted to the following:

```
Name,Age,Year,Value
ABCD,11,2020,0.11
ABCD,11,2021,1
```

Note: There can be N number of years as column names and all years have to be transposed. Will regex be a correct approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` or `numpy` to modify .csv files.