# Unpivot PySpark dataframe using arguments

Tags: function, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, unpivot

I'm trying to make a function which would  unpivot PySpark dataframe using lists as arguments.

E.g. here is the code with two lists:

1 - `ignored_columns_list` for ignored (not used) columns
2 - `non_pivot_column_list` - columns that I don't want to unpivot.

All the rest columns are being unpivoted.

The function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

ignored_columns_list = ['column_name1'] # columns that I don't need
non_pivot_column_list = ['column_name2'] # columns I don't want to unpivot
    
def unpivot_columns_final(kpi_rf_df,ignored_columns_list,non_pivot_column_list): 
    
    ignored_columns_df = kpi_rf_df.drop(*ignored_columns_list)  # columns that I don't need
    non_pivot_column_df  = kpi_rf_df.select(*non_pivot_column_list)  # columns I don't want to unpivot
    unpivot_columns_df = kpi_rf_df.drop(*ignored_columns_list,*non_pivot_column_list) # Columns that I want to unpivot 
    
    unpivot_columns_df_count = len(unpivot_columns_df.columns) # count columns to use inside Expr function
    
    unpivot_df = kpi_rf_df.select(*ignored_columns_df.columns,F.expr(f"stack({unpivot_columns_df_count}, {', '.join(unpivot_columns_df.columns)}) as (value)"))
    unpivot_df = unpivot_df.select(*non_pivot_column_df.columns, F.expr(f"stack({unpivot_columns_df_count}, {str(unpivot_columns_df.columns)[1:-1]}) as (kpi)"),'value')
    
    return unpivot_df
```

The problem is that sometimes when I change columns in the list I get this error:

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'stack(6, column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, column_name4, column_name5, column_name6)' due to data type mismatch: Argument 1 (double) != Argument 6 (date); line 1 pos 0;

I tried to sort the list of columns in `expr`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of curiosity you may take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe/74027368#74027368). There's a streamlined approach to a problem very similar to yours. Only dropping some columns could be added to exactly match your case.

Your function works! But you must know that you cannot `stack` together columns containing different data types. We can see, now you are trying to stack together a column of type *double* and a column of type *date*. Spark doesn't know which data type should be assigned to the resultant column, so you get this error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i want just to add another solution for the community : the only way to bypass this exception is to cast columns to the same data type String for exemple. `df = df.select([F.col(c).cast("string") for c in df.columns])`