# Unpivot the data frame from wide to long in PySpark using melt

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, unpivot, melt

I am trying to perform melting operation on my data frame. I have tried the code below, but I am getting an error:

> A DataFrame object does not have an attribute melt. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.

```py
df_pivot_jp = JP_ch.melt(id_vars=['c_id'], var_name='views_on_character', value_name='answer')
df_pivot_gj = GJ_ch.melt(id_vars=['c_id'], var_name='views_on_character', value_name='answer')
```

Can someone please tell me what is this attribute that I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Comment: The melt method is only available for a `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame` and not on the "classical" `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`.  I assume you are working with the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
JP_ch = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('c1', 111, 1111),
     ('c2', 222, 2222),
     ('c3', 333, 3333)],
    ['c_id', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Pandas' `melt` returns this:

```py
JP_ch = JP_ch.toPandas()
df_melted_jp = JP_ch.melt(id_vars=['c_id'], var_name='views_on_character', value_name='answer')

print(df_melted_jp)
#   c_id views_on_character  answer
# 0   c1               col2     111
# 1   c2               col2     222
# 2   c3               col2     333
# 3   c1               col3    1111
# 4   c2               col3    2222
# 5   c3               col3    3333
```

---

**Spark 3.4+**

```py
df = JP_ch.melt(['c_id'], ['col2', 'col3'], 'views_on_character', 'answer')

df.show()
# +----+------------------+------+
# |c_id|views_on_character|answer|
# +----+------------------+------+
# |  c1|              col2|   111|
# |  c1|              col3|  1111|
# |  c2|              col2|   222|
# |  c2|              col3|  2222|
# |  c3|              col2|   333|
# |  c3|              col3|  3333|
# +----+------------------+------+
```

or

```py
to_melt = [c for c in JP_ch.columns if c not in {'c_id'}]
df = JP_ch.melt(['c_id'], to_melt, 'views_on_character', 'answer')

df.show()
# +----+------------------+------+
# |c_id|views_on_character|answer|
# +----+------------------+------+
# |  c1|              col2|   111|
# |  c1|              col3|  1111|
# |  c2|              col2|   222|
# |  c2|              col3|  2222|
# |  c3|              col2|   333|
# |  c3|              col3|  3333|
# +----+------------------+------+
```

---

**Older Spark versions:**

```py
to_melt = {c for c in JP_ch.columns if c not in ['c_id']}
new_names = '(views_on_character, answer)'

melt_list = [f"\'{c}\', `{c}`" for c in to_melt]
df = JP_ch.select(
    *(set(JP_ch.columns) - to_melt),
    F.expr(f"stack({len(melt_list)}, {','.join(melt_list)}) {new_names}")
)
df.show()
# +----+------------------+------+
# |c_id|views_on_character|answer|
# +----+------------------+------+
# |  c1|              col3|  1111|
# |  c1|              col2|   111|
# |  c2|              col3|  2222|
# |  c2|              col2|   222|
# |  c3|              col3|  3333|
# |  c3|              col2|   333|
# +----+------------------+------+
```