# pyspark transform column to row

Tags: sql, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have pyspark dataframe below,

[image]

I need to convert the dataframe in the following manner, I need to pivot row into a separate column and add it to corresponding month.

[image]

I have tried the following approach,
`df.groupBY("Month").pivot("col1").`
I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas_api()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.pandas_api.html) to enable Pandas API on Spark DataFrame (not to be confused with `to_pandas()`):

```
sdf = (sdf.pandas_api()
          .melt('Month', var_name='Col_name', value_name='Value')
          .to_spark())
```

Output:

```
>>> sdf.show()
+-----+--------+-----+
|Month|Col_name|Value|
+-----+--------+-----+
|    1|    Col1|   10|
|    1|    Col2|   20|
|    1|    Col3|   30|
|    1|    Col4|   40|
|    2|    Col1|   20|
|    2|    Col2|   30|
|    2|    Col3|   50|
|    2|    Col4|   60|
|    3|    Col1|   30|
|    3|    Col2|   50|
|    3|    Col3|   60|
|    3|    Col4|   70|
|    4|    Col1|   30|
|    4|    Col2|   40|
|    4|    Col3|   50|
|    4|    Col4|   80|
+-----+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code written in PySpark to transform the columns into rows

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, explode

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 10, 20, 30, 40),
                            (2, 20, 30, 50, 60),
                            (3, 30, 50, 60, 70),
                            (4, 30, 40, 50, 80)], 
                           ["Month", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"])

melted_df = df.selectExpr("Month", 
                          "stack(4, 'Col1', Col1, 'Col2', Col2, 'Col3', Col3, 'Col4', Col4) as (Col_name, Value)")

exploded_df = melted_df.select("Month", "Col_name", explode(expr("map('Value', Value)")))

final_df = exploded_df.selectExpr("Month", "Col_name", "Value as Value_new")

final_df.show()
```