# How to freeze and transpose the column in scala spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, transpose

I have this dataframe with a single row, with values that are `string`, `int`, `bool`, `array`:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 |

And I want to transpose it like this:

| col1 | col2 | Columns | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 | col3 | val3 |
| val1 | val2 | col4 | val4 |
| val1 | val2 | col5 | val5 |

The first 2 columns are to be **AS IS**, and the remaining columns need to be unpivoted.

Comment: check out [this SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41670103/8279585) for possible ways. It talks about ways in [tag:pyspark], but they can be easily replicated in scala given the function names are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the melt function to unpivot the dataframe:

```
def melt(df: DataFrame,
        idVars: Array[String],
        valueVars: Array[String],
        varName: String = "Columns",
        valueName: String = "values"): DataFrame = {

val columns = valueVars.map(c => Array(lit(c), col(c))).flatten
val varsAndVals = map(columns: _*)
df.select(idVars.map(col(_)).:+(explode(varsAndVals)): _*)
  .withColumnRenamed("key", varName)
  .withColumnRenamed("value", valueName)
}
```

then call ii:

```
melt(df, Array("col1", "col2"), Array("col3", "col4", "col5")).show()
```

gives:

```
+----+----+-------+------+
|col1|col2|Columns|values|
+----+----+-------+------+
|val1|val2|   col3|  val3|
|val1|val2|   col4|  val4|
|val1|val2|   col5|  val5|
+----+----+-------+------+
```