# stack() in spark sql - Runtime Exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

(Using apache spark version 1.6)
I referred below link to attempt unpivot feature:
[unpivot in spark-sql/pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465568/unpivot-in-spark-sql-pyspark)

The issue here I'm getting some runtime exception when executing :

```
df.select($"A", expr("stack(2, 'large', large, 'small', small) as (c, d)")).where("c is not null or b is not null")
```

Exception:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.Exception: Application failed with 1 errors: Action UnPivot3: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.10] failure: identifier expected
stack(2, 'large', large,'small', small) as (c, d)
^
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.SqlParser$.parseExpression(SqlParser.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.expr(functions.scala:1076)
```

1) Any idea how to resolve this ?
2) Any documentation help regarding stack() will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack was added in this commit: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/d0d28507cacfca5919dbfb4269892d58b62e8662 for Jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16286

It's fix version is Spark 2.0, so you must update your Spark version to at least 2.0 to use Stack function

Comment: Is there any alternative in 1.6 to achieve same functionality ? I cant change the spark version which is deployed in server.

Comment: @Shabeel I don't think so, but it's out of question scope ;) You can try explode function