# Compare the columns with largest value, and assign a value based on column name

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm working on a case that I don't know how to solve, the original table looks like this:

| id | typeA | typeB | typeC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

I want to add a classification based on the value from typeA, B and C. The classification would be the one that has the highest value, and if there's a tie, I will push can't decide.

So the output looks like this.

| id | typeA | typeB | typeC | classification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 1 | typeB |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | typeC |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | can't decide |

I know I can use CASE WHEN in this case, but we have many "type" columns (40+), Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, there is not a good way to do this, although it is possible.

Comment: By saying possible, do you mean using something like CASE WHEN?

Comment: @ErinLiu Does the proposed answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

With 40+ columns, it may be a lot of work to implement the logic using a CASE WHEN eg.

```sql
CASE
    WHEN typeA > typeB AND typeA > typeC THEN 'typeA'
    ...etc
END
```

Another approach may be to let the database do the work with ranking and agreggrate functions as shown below. I've unpivoted the data with the first CTE `all_data` and added a meta column. You may also explore this  [other amazon athena approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64164798/4307136) if desired. I then continued to rank the data to find which type was the largest. I then determined whether there were multiple types ranked the same similar to row `3` where `typeA` and `typeB` had the same value. A case statement then decided whether I would use the actual type or `can't decide`. With the classification for each row id, I then used an inner join to add this new column to the final projection. See [sample](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qhJvq4KfjZ3djSdnkxfw2j/0) below:

```sql
WITH all_data AS (
    SELECT id, typeA as val, 'typeA' as type from my_table UNION ALL
    SELECT id, typeB as val, 'typeB' as type from my_table UNION ALL
    SELECT id, typeC as val, 'typeC' as type from my_table 
),
ranked_data AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        val,
        type,
        rank() over (partition by id order by val desc) as rnk
    FROM
        all_data     
),
classification AS (
   SELECT
       id,
       CASE 
           WHEN COUNT(id) > 1 THEN 'undecided'
           ELSE MAX(type)
       END as  class_type
   FROM
       ranked_data
   WHERE rnk=1
   GROUP BY id
   
)
SELECT
     m.*,
     c.class_type as classification
FROM
     my_table m
INNER JOIN
     classification c ON c.id = m.id
```