# In Pyspark how do I take multiple columns and make the names one column and the values another column?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

| Date | Bought | Delivered | Returned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/05/2021 | 1054 | 1036 | 13 |
| 07/06/2021 | 2036 | 2015 | 21 |

I need it to ultimately look like this:

| Date | Step | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07/05/2021 | Bought | 1054 |
| 07/05/2021 | Delivered | 1036 |
| 07/05/2021 | Returned | 13 |
| 07/06/2021 | Bought | 2036 |
| 07/06/2021 | Delivered | 2015 |
| 07/06/2021 | Returned | 21 |

What I have tried so far is just making a bunch of different tables and then I union them at the end. But this takes too much time and I was hoping to find a much better way to do this. And since this is multiple columns the explode isn't what I am looking for. But that's all I can find here on stackoverflow so any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: unpivot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211169/how-to-unpivot-a-large-spark-dataframe/60212279#60212279