# Unpivot in spark-sql/Scala column names are numbers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, stack, unpivot

I have tried the built in stack function described in this post [Unpivot in spark-sql/pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465568/unpivot-in-spark-sql-pyspark) for Scala, and works fine for each of the columns identified with a code that contains a letter but not in those columns where the code is just a number.

I have a dataframe df that looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb1p4.png)

I applied as mentioned in the linked answer:

```
val result = df.select($"Id", expr("stack(3, '00C', 00C, '0R5', 0R5, '234', 234)"))
```

And the result [is this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fmSs.png)

What I want is that the value of the row 234 was 0 [as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NotOm.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **234** is number & In SQL, If you select any number It will return same number as value, You need to tell compiler 234 is column name not number, to do that you have to use backtick (`) around the number i.e **`234`**.

Check below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("xyz",0,1,0)).toDF("Id","00C","0R5","234")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Id: string, 00C: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.select($"Id", expr("stack(3, '00C', 00C, '0R5', 0R5, '234',`234`)")).show(false)
+---+----+----+
|Id |col0|col1|
+---+----+----+
|xyz|00C |0   |
|xyz|0R5 |1   |
|xyz|234 |0   |
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: was spending lot of hours on this, your answer helped! thanks!