# pyspark how to unpivot the csv with two header lines

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

How can I use pyspark or pandas to achieve the below transformation? Thanks a lot.
Source File is csv with following info:

[image]

expected:

[image]

Comment: can you add a code to create your sample data and what you have tried until now and where you are stuck?

Comment: the source file is csv file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot in spark-sql/pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465568/unpivot-in-spark-sql-pyspark)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your source CSV file is as follows:

```
 ,Group_1,Group_2
 ,Sub_Group_1,Sub_Group_1
Maturity,7/31/20,7/31/20
0.1,0.2,0.3
0.2,0.3,0.4
```

Note that:

- there are **initial spaces** in first 2 rows (names of 2 top MultiIndex
  levels for the first column), otherwise *read_csv* would give them
  *Unnamed...* default names,
- there are actually **3** MultiIndex levels on columns (the third level
  contains dates).

I read them calling `df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', header=[0,1,2])` and the
content is:

```
               Group_1     Group_2
           Sub_Group_1 Sub_Group_1
  Maturity     7/31/20     7/31/20
0      0.1         0.2         0.3
1      0.2         0.3         0.4
```

(you should have included it instead of a picture).

The first step is *melt*:

```
result = pd.melt(df, id_vars=[(' ', ' ', 'Maturity')],
    var_name=['Group_Name', 'Sub_Group_Name', 'Date'])
```

Note that in the above code I specified *id_vars* as a **tuple**,
with 2 top elements as spaces (this is why I made the assumption about
initial spaces).

The result is:

```
   ( ,  , Maturity) Group_Name Sub_Group_Name     Date  value
0               0.1    Group_1    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.2
1               0.2    Group_1    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.3
2               0.1    Group_2    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.3
3               0.2    Group_2    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.4
```

And the only thing to do is to rename the first column:

```
result.rename(columns={result.columns[0]: 'Maturity'}, inplace=True)
```

Now, when you print the result, you will get:

```
   Maturity Group_Name Sub_Group_Name     Date  value
0       0.1    Group_1    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.2
1       0.2    Group_1    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.3
2       0.1    Group_2    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.3
3       0.2    Group_2    Sub_Group_1  7/31/20    0.4
```

The row ordering is a bit different, but this is the way *melt* works.
If you are unhappy about this detail, reorder rows according to your
needs.