# Transpose each record into multiple columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to transpose each record into multiple columns in pyspark dataframe.

This is my dataframe:

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+
|level_1 |level_2      |level_3       |level_4     |UNQ_ID|
+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+
|D  Group|Investments  |ORB           |ECM         |1     |
|E  Group|Investment   |Origination   |Execution   |2     |
+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+
```

Required dataframe is:

```
+--------+---------------+------+
|level   |name           |UNQ_ID|
+--------+---------------+------+
|level_1 |D  Group       |1     |
|level_1 |E  Group       |2     |
|level_2 |Investments    |1     |
|level_2 |Investment     |2     |
|level_3 |ORB            |1     |
|level_3 |Origination    |2     |
|level_4 |ECM            |1     |
|level_4 |Execution      |2     |
+--------+---------------+------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Hi need help to get the required dataframe format

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673644/9840637) shows exactly that. please refer the same and let us know if you are facing issues with this. There are examples as well to show how it works

Comment: ya thanks for your quick help....its working for me

Comment: @anky That answer is outdated. [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465568/unpivot-in-spark-sql-pyspark) is the current function to use.

Comment: @Kafels duplicate list should be edited then..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way using [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#stack) function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

output_df = df.selectExpr('stack(4, "level_1", level_1, "level_2", level_2, "level_3", level_3, "level_4", level_4) as (level, name)', 'UNQ_ID')
output_df.show()

# +-------+-----------+------+
# |  level|       name|UNQ_ID|
# +-------+-----------+------+
# |level_1|    D Group|     1|
# |level_2|Investments|     1|
# |level_3|        ORB|     1|
# |level_4|        ECM|     1|
# |level_1|    E Group|     2|
# |level_2|Investments|     2|
# |level_3|Origination|     2|
# |level_4|  Execution|     2|
# +-------+-----------+------+
```