# How to unpivot pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, unpivot

How can i transform the first dataframe into the second dataframe as shown in the image with pyspark?  I did some research and i want something like the function unpivot. The column "Ano" is the year.

At the moment i have this code based on this link [Unpivot in Spark SQL / PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465568/unpivot-in-spark-sql-pyspark) :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
data = [("High Paper Grade", 0.007,0.005,0.001,0.026,0.013,0.009,0.001,0.059,"Paper"), ("Mixed Low Grade Paper", 0.087,0.068,0.024,0.314,0.093,0.074,0.024,0.319,"Paper")]
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("Material",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("2017_Aggregate",FloatType(),True), \
    StructField("2017_Refuse",FloatType(),True), \
    StructField("2017_MGP", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("2017_Paper", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("2013_Aggregate", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("2013_Refuse", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("2013_MGP", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("2013_Paper", FloatType(), True), \
    StructField("Material_Group", StringType(), True)                  
  ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

df=df.selectExpr("Material","Material_Group","stack(8,'2017_Aggregate',2017_Aggregate,'2017_Refuse',2017_Refuse,'2017_MGP',2017_MGP,'2017_Paper',2017_Paper,'2013_Aggregate',2013_Aggregate,'2013_Refuse', 2013_Refuse,'2013_MGP',2013_MGP,'2013_Paper',2013_Paper) as (Year,Value)").where("Value is not null").show()


df = df.withColumn("Year", when(df.Year == "2017_Aggregate", "2017") 
                   .when (df.Year == "2017_Aggregate", "2017") 
                   .when (df.Year == "2017_Refuse", "2017")
                   .when (df.Year == "2017_MGP", "2017")
                   .when (df.Year == "2017_Paper", "2017")
                   .when (df.Year == "2013_Aggregate", "2013") 
                   .when (df.Year == "2013_Refuse", "2013")
                   .when (df.Year == "2013_MGP", "2013")
                   .when (df.Year == "2013_Paper", "2013")              
    .otherwise(df.Year) 
)
df.toPandas()
```

Which gives me the following output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJNz.png)

This is what i am trying to achieve:

[image: Dataframes]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot in spark-sql/pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465568/unpivot-in-spark-sql-pyspark)

Comment: @ScootCork I edited my post based on that link, but it´s still not what i am trying to do!

Comment: afaik there is no specific function for this, but you can achieve this by unioning the df to itself with different column selections for each year, adding the actual year as a literal column. If you have many years you can write something dynamic.