# How to efficiently transpose PySpark dataframe with one row and many integer columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, data-analysis

Say I have a df with this structure:

```
Long    Long    Long    Long    Long    Long
A   B   C   D   E   F
4   2   7   9   1   3
```

How do I efficiently transpose such that it ends up like:

```
String  Long
name    value
A   4
B   2
C   7
D   9
E   1
F   3
```

I have a solution using `df.collect()` but it takes a long time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot in Spark SQL / PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465568/unpivot-in-spark-sql-pyspark)

Comment: He want to transpose not Pivot

Comment: Something is missing in the question you posted. There is no String value in the sample you shared. It would be easier to help you if you can post what you have tried so far. Also `collect()` will be slow because it collects all the data you have in a dataframe into driver node which might end up in OOM in case the data is more than it can be collected in spark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @Frosty The strings are the column names

Comment: @samkart potentially but if there is a more efficient implementation for the case of one row, all integers, no none values, that is best.