# Column-wise processing on spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Are there efficient ways to process data column-wise (vs row-wise) in spark?

I'd like to do some whole-database analysis of each column. I'd like to iterate through each column in a database and compare it to another column with a significance test.

```
colA = "select id, colA from table1"

foreach table, t:
   foreach id,colB in t: # "select id, colB from table2"
     # align colA,colB by ID
     ab = join(colA,colB)
     yield comparefunc(ab)
```

I have ~1M rows but ~10k  columns.
Issuing ~10k selects is very slow, but shouldn't I be able to do a select * and broadcast each column to a different node for processing.

Comment: Have you considered transposing (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864222/transpose-column-to-row-with-spark) your RDD and then working on rows instead?

Comment: The big downside of K,V representations is that the type of the value is aliased (because spark column have a single type). Its *possible* to convert everything into doubles (e.g. replacing strings with a label ID). But it ain't pretty.

Comment: I've been thinking that converted the data into parquet files (one per column) may help. Though the implementation seems very broken for py-spark:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21392