# Transform data in spark scala column to row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, transform

Input Dataset:

```
CustomerID CustomerName Sun Mon Tue
   1          ABC        0   12  10
   2          DEF        10   0   0
```

Required Output Dataset:

```
CustomerID CustomerName Day  Value
    1         ABC       Sun   0
    1         ABC       Mon   12
    1         ABC       Tue   10
    2         DEF       Sun   10
    2         DEF       Mon   0
    2         DEF       Tue   0
```

Please note, that the number of "Sun Mon Tue" columns are 82 in my dataset!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864222/transpose-column-to-row-with-spark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your input `dataset` is generated using a `case class` as

```
case class infos(CustomerID: Int, CustomerName: String, Sun: Int, Mon: Int, Tue: Int)
```

For testing purpose I am creating a `dataset` as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val ds = Seq(
  infos(1, "ABC", 0, 12, 10),
  infos(2, "DEF", 10, 0, 0)
).toDS
```

which should give your input `dataset`

```
+----------+------------+---+---+---+
|CustomerID|CustomerName|Sun|Mon|Tue|
+----------+------------+---+---+---+
|1         |ABC         |0  |12 |10 |
|2         |DEF         |10 |0  |0  |
+----------+------------+---+---+---+
```

Getting your final required `dataset` requires you to create another `case class` as

```
case class finalInfos(CustomerID: Int, CustomerName: String, Day: String, Value: Int)
```

Final required `dataset` can be achieved by doing the following

```
val names = ds.schema.fieldNames

ds.flatMap(row => Array(finalInfos(row.CustomerID, row.CustomerName, names(2), row.Sun),
  finalInfos(row.CustomerID, row.CustomerName, names(3), row.Mon),
  finalInfos(row.CustomerID, row.CustomerName, names(4), row.Tue)))
```

which should give you `dataset` as

```
+----------+------------+---+-----+
|CustomerID|CustomerName|Day|Value|
+----------+------------+---+-----+
|1         |ABC         |Sun|0    |
|1         |ABC         |Mon|12   |
|1         |ABC         |Tue|10   |
|2         |DEF         |Sun|10   |
|2         |DEF         |Mon|0    |
|2         |DEF         |Tue|0    |
+----------+------------+---+-----+
```