# Transpose operation on pyspark data frame using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, transpose

I am new to python and pyspark, I have done transpose operation using pandas `df.T`. I have found that there is no direct operation on the pyspark dataframe (pyspark version = 2.2.0 and python version = 3.6.2)

I am loading a CSV file for the above operation using the following code

`from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sql = SQLContext(spark_context)
path = 'sample.csv'
df = (sql.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(path))`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to perform transpose operation on pysaprk data frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose column to row with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864222/transpose-column-to-row-with-spark)

Answer (score 0):

What is your data schema?

If it is some sort of sparse matrix, you can load with regular RDD and map + swap your coords.