# How can I get the column names which have top 3 largest values for each row in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

Sample Dataframe

```
id  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
0   5  23   4   1   4   5
1   6  43   2   2   98   43
2   3  56   3   1  23   3
3   2   2   6   3   5   2
4   5   6   7   2   7   5
```

I need like this....

```
top1 top2 top3
a2   a1   a6
a5   a2   a6
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864222/transpose-column-to-row-with-spark. This post can get you started, post your query once you try this.

Comment: I tired with pyspark.sql.functions.greatest().... but it 
returns the greatest value of the list but not column names.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, array, sort_array
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = sc.parallelize([(0, 5, 23, 4, 1, 4, 5),
                     (1, 6, 43, 2, 2, 98, 43),
                     (2, 3, 56, 3, 1, 23, 3),
                     (3, 2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 2),
                     (4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 7, 5)]).\
    toDF(["id","a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6"])
df_col = df.columns

df = df.\
    withColumn("top1_val", sort_array(array([col(x) for x in df_col[1:]]), asc=False)[0]).\
    withColumn("top2_val", sort_array(array([col(x) for x in df_col[1:]]), asc=False)[1]).\
    withColumn("top3_val", sort_array(array([col(x) for x in df_col[1:]]), asc=False)[2])

def modify_values(r, max_col):
    l = []
    for i in range(len(df_col[1:])):
        if r[i]== max_col:
            l.append(df_col[i+1])
    return l
modify_values_udf = udf(modify_values, StringType())

df1 = df.\
    withColumn("top1", modify_values_udf(array(df.columns[1:-3]), "top1_val")).\
    withColumn("top2", modify_values_udf(array(df.columns[1:-3]), "top2_val")).\
    withColumn("top3", modify_values_udf(array(df.columns[1:-3]), "top3_val"))
df1.show()
```

Output is:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| id| a1| a2| a3| a4| a5| a6|top1_val|top2_val|top3_val|    top1|    top2|        top3|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|  0|  5| 23|  4|  1|  4|  5|      23|       5|       5|    [a2]|[a1, a6]|    [a1, a6]|
|  1|  6| 43|  2|  2| 98| 43|      98|      43|      43|    [a5]|[a2, a6]|    [a2, a6]|
|  2|  3| 56|  3|  1| 23|  3|      56|      23|       3|    [a2]|    [a5]|[a1, a3, a6]|
|  3|  2|  2|  6|  3|  5|  2|       6|       5|       3|    [a3]|    [a5]|        [a4]|
|  4|  5|  6|  7|  2|  7|  5|       7|       7|       6|[a3, a5]|[a3, a5]|        [a2]|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
```