# Transpose Dataframe rows and columns to Key-Value Pair

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as below now I need to transpose the data output as key-Value pair. Where Key being the ColumnName and Value as the columnsValue.

```
+---+----+------+-----+
|age| dob|gender| name|
+---+----+------+-----+
| 25|1991|     M|Ankit|
+---+----+------+-----+
```

Required Output

```
+-------+-------+
|Key    |Value  |
+-------+-------+
|age    |25     |
|dob    |1991   |
|gender |M      |
|name   |Ankit  |
+-------+-------+
```

I tried using the sample code given in the following link https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/pyspark-code-that-turns-columns-into-rows

But this gives me an error as below,

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o149.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help on this aspect would be really helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose column to row with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864222/transpose-column-to-row-with-spark)

Comment: @pault had tried the same too but it didn't seem to work, the answer provided by you below worked like charm. Thanks a ton

Comment: @user10938362 had tried that piece of code too but didnt get the expected output, if you can explain me the code used in that link would be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option in this case would be create a `MapType` of your columns and `explode`:

```python
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, explode, lit

df.select(
    explode(create_map(*chain.from_iterable([(lit(c), col(c)) for c in df.columns])))
).show()
#+------+-----+
#|   key|value|
#+------+-----+
#|   age|   25|
#|   dob| 1991|
#|gender|    M|
#|  name|Ankit|
#+------+-----+
```

Comment: Single line code, works wonders :) Thanks. If you don't mind, can you please explain what's happening within the single line code.

Comment: @Joby `create_map` takes in an even number of arguments, which are alternating keys and values. The list comprehension creates tuples of the literal value of the column (`lit(c)`) and the column value `col(c)` for every column in your dataframe. `chain.from_iterable` flattens this nested structure, and the `*` operator is used to unpack the arguments to pass them to `create_map`. Finally use `explode` to turn the `MapType` into rows of `key` and `value`.