Spark scala transformations
I have spark input dataframe like below.



Emp_ID
Cricket
Chess
Swim




11
Y
N
N


12
Y
Y
Y


13
N
N
Y



Need Out Dataframe like below.



Hobbies
Emp_id_list




Cricket
11,12


Chess
12


Swim
12,13



Any way to achieve this in efficient way in scala Spark would help ..
I have tried creating multiple dataframe(each for one hobby) and union of all 3.  Need a efficient way.

This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864222/transpose-column-to-row-with-spark

Please add hobbies table as well, what do you want to do, join? Probably there are already answers to this question...
