# Best approach for looping through a csv file in spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I am following some of the basic example in the documentation.

I have a csv file like this: (a simplified version, the real one has nearly 40,000 lines)

```
date,category
19900108,apples
19900108,apples
19900308,peaches
19900408,peaches
19900508,pears
19910108,pears
19910108,peaches
19910308,apples
19910408,apples
19910508,apples
19920108,pears
19920108,peaches
19920308,apples
19920408,peaches
19920508,pears
```

This bit of scala code works fine for counting category totals

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("sample.csv")
textFile.filter(line => line.contains("1990")).filter(line =>line.contains("peaches")).count()
textFile.filter(line => line.contains("1990")).filter(line => line.contains("apples")).count()
textFile.filter(line => line.contains("1990")).filter(line => line.contains("pears")).count()
```

What is the best approach for looping through each line, adding category totals by year so that I end up writing a csv file like this:

```
date,apples,peaches,pears
1990,2,2,1
1991,3,1,1
1992,1,2,2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivot Spark Dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/pivot-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create Spark SQL Context    
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

//read csv
var df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("sample.csv")
df = df.withColumn("year", df.col("date").substr(0,4))
df = df.groupBy("year").pivot("category").agg("category"->"count")
df.withColumn("total", df.col("apples").+(df.col("peaches")).+(df.col("pears"))).show()

//Dependency required:
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: [Spark 2.0](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html#new-features) was released recently, it now has native CSV support :)

Comment: Thanks VenkatN for your answer. I've been under the weather the past few days so I haven't been able to look at this sooner.

When I run this script I get an "error reassignment val" message at this line: 
df = df.withColumn("year", df.col("date").substr(0,4))

With Spark 2,0 does this mean I don't have t include the databricks csv package?

Comment: I declared "df" as var instead of val for the same reason. So, to avoid "error reassignment val" you have to do the same thing or you can initialize a new variable instead of reassigning it to df like:

`val df2 = df.withColumn("year", df.col("date").substr(0,4))`
`df2.groupBy("year").pivot("category").agg("category"->"count").show()`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it. My mistake was using "val df" instead of "var df" I have been fighting a head cold the last few days andI can't think straight What if I wanted a total column so my CSV file will look like this:

         date,total,apples,peaches,pears
        1990,5,2,2,1

Comment: Please check the updated answer, that should help you.

Comment: ok thanks. When i run the code it seems to work fine. It shows year, apples,peaches,pears and correct data on the console

Yet when I write a csv file I get this; (date,category,year
19900108,apples,1990
19900108,apples,1990
19900308,peaches,1990
, etc)

It is taking the loaded csv and appending the year column. I am usig this:

df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("mydata.csv")

Comment: This is the output from the code above, I don't see what you are seeing.
`+----+------+-------+-----+-----+
|year|apples|peaches|pears|total|
+----+------+-------+-----+-----+
|1990|     2|      2|    1|    5|
|1991|     3|      1|    1|    5|
|1992|     1|      2|    2|    5|
+----+------+-------+-----+-----+`