# Using Dataframe instead of spark sql for data analysis

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is the sample spark sql I wrote to get the count of male and female enrolled in an agency.I used sql to generate the output,
Is there a way to do similar thing using dataframe only  not sql.

```
val districtWiseGenderCountDF = hiveContext.sql("""
                                                   | SELECT District, 
                                                   |        count(CASE WHEN Gender='M' THEN 1 END) as male_count, 
                                                   |        count(CASE WHEN Gender='F' THEN 1 END) as FEMALE_count 
                                                   | FROM agency_enrollment 
                                                   | GROUP BY District
                                                   | ORDER BY male_count DESC, FEMALE_count DESC
                                                   | LIMIT 10""".stripMargin)
```

Comment: what version of spark are you using?

Comment: I am using spark 2 in Hortonworks sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Spark 1.6 you can use pivot + group by to achieve what you'd like

without sample data (and my own availability of spark>1.5) here's a solution that Should work (not tested)

```
val df = hiveContext.table("agency_enrollment")
df.groupBy("district","gender").pivot("gender").count
```

see [How to pivot DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-dataframe) for a generic example