# pivot in PYSPARKSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a requirement to use pivot on below table.

```
id,week,score
102,1,96
101,1,138
102,1,37
101,1,59
101,2,282
102,2,212
102,2,78
101,2,97
102,3,60
102,3,123
101,3,220
101,3,87
```

output

```
      1         2         3

101   138,59   282,97     220,87
102   96,37    212,78     123,60
```

here i need to sort score

i have tried below code but it only works when there is a single record on a particular id

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("week").agg(first("score"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-dataframe)

Comment: No shankar, Here i am expecting all records as an array..please check the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `first` you should be collecting all the values using `collect_list`, this will give you the result in list

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.groupBy("id").pivot("week").agg(collect_list("score")).show()
```

output :

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|id |1        |2        |3        |
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|101|[138, 59]|[282, 97]|[220, 87]|
|102|[96, 37] |[212, 78]|[60, 123]|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: May i get the above output using sql query in pyspark by using temptable.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent *python* code for pyspark for the *scala* answer posted by Prasad Khode is as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy("id").pivot("week").agg(F.collect_list("score")).show()
```

If you check the api document you can see

> collect_list(Column e)
>   Aggregate function: returns a list of objects with duplicates.

You can use `collect_set` as well which will give you the same output with duplicates removed.

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("week").agg(F.collect_set("score")).show()
```

api document says the following

> collect_set(Column e)
>   Aggregate function: returns a set of objects with duplicate elements eliminated.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ramesh, May i have a chance of getting same output using sql query in pyspark.
i have used this query which shows error "select id,list((case when week = 1 then score else null end) as `1`,','),list((case when week = 2 then score else null end) as `2`,','),list((case when week = 3 then score else null end) as `3`,',') from d group by id"

Comment: @LUZO, I am afraid I can't be a good help on that as sql queries are nightmares for me. :) you can post another question with much detail explaining your requirements. You will certainly get an answer.