# Pivoting Data-frame in PYSPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pivot, apache-spark-sql

i have a requirement as below

dataframe

```
id   code
R101,GTR001
R201,RTY987
R301,KIT158
R201,PLI564
R101,MJU098
R301,OUY579
```

There can be many `code`s per `id` (not only two).

The expected output should be as below.

```
id    col1  col2   col3   col4   col5   col6

R101 GTR001 MJU098 null   null   null   null   
R201 null   null   RTY987 PLI564 null   null   
R301 null   null   null   null   KIT158 OUY579
```

Here columns for particular `id` depends on the number of `code`s assigned to that `id`, i.e. under `col1` and `col2` code for `R101` should be populated, under `col3` and `col4` code for `R201` should be populated and the same goes for remaining ids.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-dataframe)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162275/discussion-between-ashsr-and-philantrovert).

Comment: Can the same `code`, e.g. `GTR001`, be assigned to two or more `id`s?

Comment: No Jacek, code is unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try ranking the code field based on id and use the rank for pivoting.Hope this helps,

```
 df = spark.createDataFrame([('R101','GTR001'),('R201','RTY987'),('R301','KIT158'),('R201','PLI564'),('R101','MJU098'),('R301','OUY579')],['id','code'])
 df.show()
   +----+------+
   |  id|  code|
   +----+------+
   |R101|GTR001|
   |R201|RTY987|
   |R301|KIT158|
   |R201|PLI564|
   |R101|MJU098|
   |R301|OUY579|
   +----+------+

 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 from pyspark.sql import Window

 df = df.withColumn('rank',F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("id","code")))
 df.withColumn('combcol',F.concat(F.lit('col_'),df['rank'])).groupby('id').pivot('combcol').agg(F.first('code')).show()

    +----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
   |  id| col_1| col_2| col_3| col_4| col_5| col_6|
   +----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
   |R101|GTR001|MJU098|  null|  null|  null|  null|
   |R201|  null|  null|PLI564|RTY987|  null|  null|
   |R301|  null|  null|  null|  null|KIT158|OUY579|
   +----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```