# sparklyr's dataframe transformer fails at pivoting?

Tags: r, sparklyr

I tried to use the pipeline ideology in building an ML routine in `sparklyr`.

Apparently the `ft_dplyr_transformer` does not support table pivoting, since this part:

```
%>% sdf_pivot(formula = Who + time_period ~ What_Action, fun.aggregate = "count") %>%
              na.replace(0)
```

crushes the overall result. If I omit it, the rest works just fine.

**Is this really the case, or I miss some of the basics of the pipelining?**

```
spark_ml_pipeline <- 
     ml_pipeline(r_spark_connection) %>%
     ft_dplyr_transformer(
          preprocessed_spark_df %>%
          mutate(
               time_period = if(Date < '2017-12-01') {
                    'train_period'
               } else {
                    'test_period'
               }
          ) %>%
          mutate(
               What_Action = translate(What_Action, ' ', '_')
          ) %>%
          filter(
               !ObjectType %in% c('logon')
          ) %>%
          sdf_pivot(formula = Who + time_period ~ What_Action, fun.aggregate = "count") %>%
          na.replace(0)
     )
```

A help for the function reads:

> Implements the transformations which are defined by SQL statement.
>   Currently we only support SQL syntax like 'SELECT ... FROM **THIS**
>   ...' where '**THIS**' represents the underlying table of the input
>   dataset.

Comment: This sounds about right. There is no pivoting operator in SQL. It belongs to `DataFrame` API.  You can do it by hand (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30397833/6910411)).

Comment: "There is no pivoting operator in SQL" are you referring to the spark.sql library https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$? In general, SQl does have pivot/unpivot functions. OK, thank you for the manual method. I think sometimes it will be helpful.

Comment: `ft_dplyr_transformer()` only supports stuff that can get translated to SQL, and as @user6910411 mentioned, `sdf_pivot()` calls the `pivot` method of `DataFrame` and hence can't be part of a pipeline.