# Pivot in SPARK SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Can someone help me how to do a pivot in spark sql? I have been struggling to get this query running.

Here is my requirement:

`country    date    customer    attribute_name  attribute_value attribute_creation`

`US 23-Apr-17   Vasan   price_start_time    4/6/18 1:23 4/6/18 1:23`

`US 23-Apr-17   Vasan   price_end_time  4/7/18 1:23 4/6/18 1:23`
`US 23-Apr-17   Vasan   price_status    MATCH   4/6/18 1:23`

`US 23-Apr-17   Vasan   price_type  Deal    4/6/18 1:23`

`US 23-Apr-17   Gaesh   price_start_time    5/6/18 1:23 5/6/18 1:23`

`US 23-Apr-17   Gaesh   price_end_time  5/7/18 1:23 5/6/18 1:23`

`US 23-Apr-17   Gaesh   price_status    MATCH   5/6/18 1:23`

`US 23-Apr-17   Gaesh   price_type  Deal    5/6/18 1:23`

For a SQL (oracle), I would write my query like this,

`(select asin,PPST,PPET,PS,PPT from (select * from meta_data where country='US' and date=to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYY/MM/DD}','YYYY/MM/DD'))
pivot (
    max(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE) for ATTRIBUTE_NAME in ('price_start_time' PPST,'price_end_time' PPET,'price_status' PS,'price_type' PPT)
))`

but for spark sql, I am not sure if there is PIVOT option. Any reference or guidance or query is really appreciative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)

Comment: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

There was no PIVOT in Spark using the SQL API until spark 2.4

After Spark 2.4 the PIVOT functionality in SQL works as you describe it.