# Pivot a spark dataframe without a groupBy column

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I've a dataframe something like this,

```
+---+----+------+
|id |name|salary|
+---+----+------+
|10 |abc |100   |
+---+----+------+
```

And I would like to pivot/transpose the data so that the output looks like,

```
+--------+----+
|col_name|data|
+--------+----+
|id      |10  |
|name    |abc |
|salary  |100 |
+--------+----+
```

How would I do this using pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stack as

```
s = ','.join([f"'{i}', `{i}`" for i in df.columns])
df = df.select([col(i).cast('string') for i in df.columns])
df.select(expr(f'''stack({len(df.columns)},{s})''')).show()

+------+----+
|  col0|col1|
+------+----+
|    id|  10|
|  name| abc|
|salary| 100|
+------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham. This works but I want to ask why do you have to cast the columns to string?

Comment: Stack requires all columns as string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a spark function that does that. You could use **expr(stack(...))** or do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378047/pyspark-dataframe-melt-columns-into-rows).