need output in pyspark code that convert given data to required output without using stack
Input data:
enter image description here
output data:
enter image description here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64179870/3238085  , you can use melt or unpivot.
melt() is an alias for unpivot().

ab=ab.melt(ids=["id","emp_id","comp_id","site_id","emp_name"],values=["location","doj","status","time"], variableColumnName='Description', 
                  valueColumnName='value')


melt() is an alias for unpivot().

Here's a more complicated way to do it.
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from itertools import chain

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("NoUnstack").getOrCreate()


schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("emp_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("comp_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("site_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("emp_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("emp_address", StringType(), True),
    StructField("join_date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("status", StringType(), True),
    StructField("time", StringType(), True)
])


data = [
    ("aaa111", "emp_123", "123-1", "rrr1", "aaa sdf er", "mumbai", "22-4-2024", "active", "5:00"),
    ("aaa222", "emp_124", "123-2", "rrr2", "aaae sdf er", "jalna", "22-4-2025", "inactive", "6:00"),
    ("aaa333", "emp_125", "123-3", "rrr3", "aaa sdef er", "pune", "22-4-2026", "active", "7:00")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()

map_cols = ["emp_name", "emp_address", "join_date", "status", "time"]
id_cols = ["id", "emp_id", "comp_id", "site_id"]

new_value = list(chain(*[ (lit(c), col(c)) for c in map_cols] ))
print(*new_value)


df_with_map = df.withColumn("attributes", create_map( *new_value )).drop(*map_cols)
df_with_map.show(truncate=False)

df_exploded = df_with_map.select(*id_cols,  explode(col("attributes")).alias("description", "values"))
df_exploded.show(truncate=False)

Output:
+------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+----+
|    id| emp_id|comp_id|site_id|   emp_name|emp_address|join_date|  status|time|
+------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+----+
|aaa111|emp_123|  123-1|   rrr1| aaa sdf er|     mumbai|22-4-2024|  active|5:00|
|aaa222|emp_124|  123-2|   rrr2|aaae sdf er|      jalna|22-4-2025|inactive|6:00|
|aaa333|emp_125|  123-3|   rrr3|aaa sdef er|       pune|22-4-2026|  active|7:00|
+------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+----+

Column<'emp_name'> Column<'emp_name'> Column<'emp_address'> Column<'emp_address'> Column<'join_date'> Column<'join_date'> Column<'status'> Column<'status'> Column<'time'> Column<'time'>
+------+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id    |emp_id |comp_id|site_id|attributes                                                                                               |
+------+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|aaa111|emp_123|123-1  |rrr1   |{emp_name -> aaa sdf er, emp_address -> mumbai, join_date -> 22-4-2024, status -> active, time -> 5:00}  |
|aaa222|emp_124|123-2  |rrr2   |{emp_name -> aaae sdf er, emp_address -> jalna, join_date -> 22-4-2025, status -> inactive, time -> 6:00}|
|aaa333|emp_125|123-3  |rrr3   |{emp_name -> aaa sdef er, emp_address -> pune, join_date -> 22-4-2026, status -> active, time -> 7:00}   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|id    |emp_id |comp_id|site_id|description|values     |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|aaa111|emp_123|123-1  |rrr1   |emp_name   |aaa sdf er |
|aaa111|emp_123|123-1  |rrr1   |emp_address|mumbai     |
|aaa111|emp_123|123-1  |rrr1   |join_date  |22-4-2024  |
|aaa111|emp_123|123-1  |rrr1   |status     |active     |
|aaa111|emp_123|123-1  |rrr1   |time       |5:00       |
|aaa222|emp_124|123-2  |rrr2   |emp_name   |aaae sdf er|
|aaa222|emp_124|123-2  |rrr2   |emp_address|jalna      |
|aaa222|emp_124|123-2  |rrr2   |join_date  |22-4-2025  |
|aaa222|emp_124|123-2  |rrr2   |status     |inactive   |
|aaa222|emp_124|123-2  |rrr2   |time       |6:00       |
|aaa333|emp_125|123-3  |rrr3   |emp_name   |aaa sdef er|
|aaa333|emp_125|123-3  |rrr3   |emp_address|pune       |
|aaa333|emp_125|123-3  |rrr3   |join_date  |22-4-2026  |
|aaa333|emp_125|123-3  |rrr3   |status     |active     |
|aaa333|emp_125|123-3  |rrr3   |time       |7:00       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+

