# pyspark partial transpose of column to row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking for ways how to transform few columns to rows.
For example if my input is like below:

```
+-------+----+----------+--------+
|Country|Year|Population|     GDP|
+-------+----+----------+--------+
|    USA|2020| 331002651|21433226|
|  China|2020|1439323776|16364160|
|  India|2020|1380004385| 3140892|
+-------+----+----------+--------+
```

I wanted an output like:

```
+-------+----+----------+----------+
|Country|Year|Measure   |     Value|
+-------+----+----------+----------+
|    USA|2020|GDP       |  21433226|
|  China|2020|GDP       |  16364160|
|  India|2020|GDP       |   3140892|
|    USA|2020|Population| 331002651|
|  China|2020|Population|1439323776|
|  India|2020|Population|1380004385|
+-------+----+----------+----------+
```

I am referring quite a few like:
[PySpark Dataframe melt columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378047/pyspark-dataframe-melt-columns-into-rows)

But I am unable to translate to my requirement.

Comment: Do you have only these two columns or it is dynamic number of columns you want to transform?

Comment: Also what did you try with melt, show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#stack) to create multiple rows from a single row:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select('Country', 'Year', 
          F.expr('stack(2, "Population", Population, "GDP", GDP) as (Measure, value)')) \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+----+----------+----------+
|Country|Year|   Measure|     value|
+-------+----+----------+----------+
|    USA|2020|Population| 331002651|
|    USA|2020|       GDP|  21433226|
|  China|2020|Population|1439323776|
|  China|2020|       GDP|  16364160|
|  India|2020|Population|1380004385|
|  India|2020|       GDP|   3140892|
+-------+----+----------+----------+
```