# Transpose pyspark rows into columns

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to transpose some of my PySpark dataframe rows into columns

I've done many attempts but I can't seem to get the correct results.

Dataframe currently looks like this

```
ArticleID   |Category  |Value
1            Color      Black
1            Gender     Male
2            Color      Green
2            Gender     Female
3            Color      Blue
3            Gender     Male
```

Situation I'm trying to get is

```
ArticleID   |Color  |Gender
1            Black   Male
2            Green   Female
3            Blue    Male
```

**Edit:** Question might be the same in some areas but this one required an aggregation on first item for the pivoted row.

```
agg(f.first())
```

Suggested question could aggregate on numerical operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupBy` + `pivot`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupBy('ArticleID').pivot('Category').agg(f.first('Value')).show()
+---------+-----+------+
|ArticleID|Color|Gender|
+---------+-----+------+
|        3| Blue|  Male|
|        1|Black|  Male|
|        2|Green|Female|
+---------+-----+------+
```