# Iterate through a whole dataset at once in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a big data set with population demographics per year, per country. I'm using Apache Spark with Scala and Parquet. The structure is one column per year (i.e. '1965'). I would like to be able to select row values across the set.

Here is the schema:

```
columns: Array[String] = Array(country, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010)
```

I'd like to be able to filter my data set based on population level, regardless of what year it is. For example, get the country name and year when the population is over 500

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE population > 5000000. 

Result: Cuba, 1962
```

How can I structure my data frame to allow for this type of query?

Comment: Use "stack" grammer to transpose the dataframe and filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to pivot the table.

Here is a good article:
https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html

How to pivot a dataframe:
[How to pivot DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-dataframe)

Answer (score -1):

```
case class Demographic(country: String,
  population: Long,
  year: Int)

// Creating a strongly-typed dataset.
val dataset = Seq(
  Demographic("US",20*math.pow(10,3).toLong, 1675), 
  Demographic("US", 3*math.pow(10,8).toLong, 2018),
  Demographic("CH", math.pow(10,9).toLong, 2015))
  .toDF.as[Demographic]

// Now filtering is easy using a lambda expression.
dataset.filter(demo => demo.population > 5000)
```