# PySpark Dataframe Transformation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext('local')

df_pd = pd.DataFrame([[11, 'abc', 1, 114],
                      [11, 'abc', 2, 104],
                      [11, 'def', 9, 113],
                      [12, 'abc', 1,  14],
                      [12, 'def', 3, 110],
                      [14, 'abc', 1, 194],
                      [14, 'abc', 2, 164],
                      [14, 'abc', 3, 104],],
                      columns=['id', 'str', 'num', 'val'])

sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)

df_spark = sql_sc.createDataFrame(df_pd)
df_spark.show()
```

Which prints:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| id|str|num|val|
+---+---+---+---+
| 11|abc|  1|114|
| 11|abc|  2|104|
| 11|def|  9|113|
| 12|abc|  1| 14|
| 12|def|  3|110|
| 14|abc|  1|194|
| 14|abc|  2|164|
| 14|abc|  3|104|
+---+---+---+---+
```

My goal is to transform it to this:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|abc_1|abc_2|abc_3|def_3|def_9|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 11|  114|  104|  NaN|  NaN|  113|
| 12|   14|  NaN|  NaN|  110|  NaN|
| 14|  194|  164|  104|  NaN|  NaN|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

(One row per `id`, colum names are `str+'_'+str(val)`, the resulting table is filled with the respective `val`s, all other entries are `NaN`)

How would I achieve this?
I started with

```
column = df_spark.select(concat(col("str"), lit("_"), col("num")))
```

by which I get the column names.

```
df_spark.select('id').distinct()
```

Gives the distinct `id`s

But I fail to build the new Dataframe or fill it.

Edit: The difference to the possible duplicate is that I didnt know about the pivot functionality, whereas the other question asked where to find the function "pivot" in pyspark. I dont know if thats a duplicate or not, but I didnt find the other question because I didnt know what to look for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which kind of aggregation you want to use for val field. I used sum and here is the solution

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_spark = df_spark.withColumn('col', F.concat(F.col("str"), F.lit("_"), F.col("num")))

df_spark.groupBy('id').pivot('col').agg({'val':'sum'}).orderBy('id').show()

+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|abc_1|abc_2|abc_3|def_3|def_9|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 11|  114|  104| null| null|  113|
| 12|   14| null| null|  110| null|
| 14|  194|  164|  104| null| null|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it (there shouldnt be two entries with the same id, str and num).